# after build with "maven install" Java deserialization fails with ClassNotFoundException although Class.forName() finds the class in IDE and export

Tags: java, deserialization, spring-batch, classloader, urlclassloader

Due to use of *Spring Batch*  one of my classes needs to be serializable.
This works perfectly in the Eclipse IDE. But as soon as I build the target "maven install" and test from command line, the deserialization util of spring does not find the class although a Class.forName() **does** find it! The class to be serialized implements `Serializable` and has a `serialVersionUID`.
See code example:

```java
    import org.springframework.util.SerializationUtils;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Class.forName("de.test.JobConfig");
            System.out.println("JobConfig found as expected");

            JobConfig jc1 = new JobConfig();
            jc1.setCodePage("some string");
            byte[] stasis = SerializationUtils.serialize(jc1);
            JobConfig jc2 = (JobConfig) SerializationUtils.deserialize(stasis);
            System.out.println(jc1.equals(jc2) ? "equals" : "not equals");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("JobConfig not found!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ...
        ...
    }
```

The result is inside Eclipse IDE:
`equals`

But after 'maven install'

```
JobConfig found as expected
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to deserialize object type
        at org.springframework.util.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:75)
        at de.sopra.zeb.loader.Zeb2JiraRESTLoader.main(Zeb2JiraRESTLoader.java:75)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.test.JobConfig
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.util.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:69)
        ... 9 more
```

So, I can find the JobConfig.class in the exported JAR file even after exporting the JAR with `maven install`, what the `Class.forName()` proves. Why is this not the case for *Spring Batch*?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `de.test.JobConfig` is in the maven classpath. ([In Maven, how output the classpath being used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655010/in-maven-how-output-the-classpath-being-used))

To add a dependency to classpath, add the jar which contains `de.test.JobConfig` as a dependency in the batch applications pom.xml.