# maven build-classpath doesn't include its own module

Tags: java, maven, classpath

If I have a maven module 'my-module', I can run `dependency:build-classpath` on it, as documented here:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html

This should give me a list of all jars I need in order to run things from `my-module`.  But there's one jar missing: `my-module.jar` itself!  Any way to fix this?

Comment: check out the second answer of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655010/in-maven-how-output-the-classpath-being-used and see if it helps

Comment: YES I think it does, will look at this more hopefully tomorrow.