# Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister - BuldSession Error

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, sessionfactory

somebody know why this keeps happening?
I'm using Hibernate, Mysql, Maven, Spring.
I've looking in every post but i can't find the solution.
Thank you :)

```
Class Libro

package com.webservice.serviceDos;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "libros")
public class Libro implements java.io.Serializable
{
    private int libroIsbn;
    private String libroAutor;
    private String libroTitulo;
    private String libroTema;

    public Libro()
    {}

    public Libro(int isbn, String autor, String titulo,String tema) 
    {
        this.libroIsbn=isbn;
        this.libroAutor=autor;
        this.libroTitulo=titulo;
        this.libroTema=tema;
    }


    @Id
    @Column(name = "LIBRO_ISBN", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 5, scale = 0)
    public int getLibroIsbn() 
    {
        return this.libroIsbn;
    }

    public void setLibroIsbn(int isbn) 
    {
        this.libroIsbn=isbn;
    }

    @Column(name = "LIBRO_AUTOR", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getLibroAutor() 
    {
        return this.libroAutor;
    }

    public void setLibroAutor(String autor) {
        this.libroAutor = autor;
    }

    @Column(name = "LIBRO_TITULO", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getLibroTitulo() 
    {
        return this.libroTitulo;
    }

    public void setLibroTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.libroTitulo = titulo;
    }

    @Column(name = "LIBRO_TEMA", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getLibroTema() 
    {
        return this.libroTema;
    }

    public void setLibroTema(String tema) {
        this.libroTema = tema;
    }

//  public String toString() { 
//      return "Isbn: '" + this.libroIsbn + "' Autor: '" + this.libroAutor + "' Titulo: '" + this.libroTitulo + " 'Tema: '" + this.libroTema + "'";
//  } 


}
```

Class LibroDaoInterface

```
package com.webservice.serviceDos;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;


public interface LibroDaoInterface<T, Id extends Serializable>
{
    public void persist(T entity);
    public T findById(int id);
    public void delete(T entity);
    public List<T> findAll();
    public void deleteAll();

}
```

LibroDao

```
package com.webservice.serviceDos;

import java.util.List;


import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.webservice.serviceDos.Libro;

public class LibroDao implements LibroDaoInterface<Libro, String> 
{
    private Session currentSession;
    private Transaction currentTransaction;

    public LibroDao(){}

    public Session openCurrentSession()
    {       
        currentSession = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        return currentSession;
    }

    public Session OpenCurrentSessionwithTransaction()
    {
        currentSession = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        currentTransaction = currentSession.beginTransaction();
        return currentSession;
    }

    public void closeCurrentSession()
    {
        currentSession.close();
    }

    public void closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction()
    {
        currentTransaction.commit();
        currentSession.close();
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public Session getCurrentSession()
    {
        return currentSession;
    }

    public void setCurrentSession(Session currentSession)
    {
        this.currentSession = currentSession;
    }

    public Transaction getSessionTransaction()
    {
        return currentTransaction;
    }

    public void setCurrentTransaction(Transaction currentTransaction)
    {
        this.currentTransaction=currentTransaction;
    }

    public void persist(Libro entity)
    {
        getCurrentSession().save(entity);
    }

    public Libro findById(int id)
    {
        Libro libro = (Libro)getCurrentSession().get(Libro.class, id);
        return libro;
    }

    public void delete(Libro entity)
    {
        getCurrentSession().delete(entity);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Libro> findAll()
    {
        List<Libro> libros = (List<Libro>)getCurrentSession().createQuery("from libros").list();
        return libros;
    }

    public void deleteAll()
    {
        List<Libro> entityList = findAll();
        for(Libro entity : entityList)
        {
            delete(entity);
        }
    }       
}
```

LibroService

```
package com.webservice.serviceDos;

import java.util.List;

import com.webservice.serviceDos.Libro;
import com.webservice.serviceDos.LibroDao;

import org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException;

public class LibroService 
{
    public static LibroDao libroDao;

    public LibroService()
    {
        libroDao = new LibroDao();
    }

    public void persist(Libro entity)
    {
        try
        {
            libroDao.OpenCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
            libroDao.persist(entity);
            libroDao.closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
        }
        catch(JDBCConnectionException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);  
        }
    }

    public Libro findById(int id)
    {
        libroDao.openCurrentSession();
        Libro libro = libroDao.findById(id);
        libroDao.closeCurrentSession();
        return libro;
    }

    public void delete(int id)
    {
        libroDao.OpenCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
        Libro libro = libroDao.findById(id);
        libroDao.delete(libro);
        libroDao.closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
    }

    public List<Libro> findAll()
    {
        libroDao.openCurrentSession();
        List<Libro> libros = libroDao.findAll();
        libroDao.closeCurrentSession();
        return libros;
    }

    public void deleteAll()
    {
        libroDao.OpenCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
        libroDao.deleteAll();
        libroDao.closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
    }

    public LibroDao libroDao()
    {
        return libroDao;
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/biblioteca</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">1234</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hmb2dll.auto">update</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>        
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>                
        <mapping class="com.webservice.serviceDos.Libro"/>  
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.webservice</groupId>
  <artifactId>serviceDos</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>serviceDos</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Error

```
ago 28, 2016 4:59:16 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
ago 28, 2016 4:59:16 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
ago 28, 2016 4:59:16 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
ago 28, 2016 4:59:16 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
ago 28, 2016 4:59:16 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
ago 28, 2016 4:59:16 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
ago 28, 2016 4:59:16 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
ago 28, 2016 4:59:16 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
ago 28, 2016 4:59:16 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/biblioteca]
ago 28, 2016 4:59:16 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
ago 28, 2016 4:59:16 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
ago 28, 2016 4:59:16 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
ago 28, 2016 4:59:17 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
ago 28, 2016 4:59:17 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
ago 28, 2016 4:59:17 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
ago 28, 2016 4:59:17 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at com.webservice.serviceDos.LibroDao.getSessionFactory(LibroDao.java:49)
    at com.webservice.serviceDos.LibroDao.OpenCurrentSessionwithTransaction(LibroDao.java:29)
    at com.webservice.serviceDos.LibroService.persist(LibroService.java:23)
    at com.webservice.serviceDos.App.main(App.java:14)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:403)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:520)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:163)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:135)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/util/proxy/MethodFilter
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.javassist.BytecodeProviderImpl.getProxyFactoryFactory(BytecodeProviderImpl.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactoryInternal(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:80)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.util.proxy.MethodFilter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 26 more
```

Answer (score 3):

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/util/proxy/MethodFilter

You need to include [javassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/) in your project.  Add to pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have Javassist in my library, don't need to put it in my pom file :(

Comment: @ValentinaOppen How does Javassist get on the class path if you don't put it in your pom?

Comment: @ValentinaOppen See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410548/maven-add-a-folder-or-jar-file-into-currrent-classpath http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364114/can-i-add-jars-to-maven-2-build-classpath-without-installing-them , and very nice off-site resource http://mark.koli.ch/maven-add-local-jar-dependency-to-classpath