# scala sbt with pk11 or steps

Tags: scala, maven-2, sbt, sjson

I am quite frustrated with sbt and pk11/steps
(Why are these things never work out of the box for me?)

I am just trying to run "jetty-run", but i got so many dependency errors, it's not fun anymore.

I am stuck with unresolved dependencies for sjson 0.3

Does anyone know which mvn repo can I get sjson 0.3 from?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing obvious according to Google (version 0.4 is available [here](http://guice-maven.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/sjson/json/sjson/0.4/) though) so either:

- install it manually to your local repository using [`mvn install:install-file`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html)
- install it to an "embedded" repository as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path/2230464#2230464)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this question regarding sjson 0.3 is still relevant after 3 years since pk11/steps doesn't seem to exist any more.

After Googling, I did find http://dev.mapfish.org/maven/repository/sjson/json/sjson/0.3/ for sjson 0.3.
More recent versions of sjson such as 0.19 are available from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Csjson).