# converting websphere portal project to maven

Tags: maven-2, websphere-portal

I am working on converting websphere portal project to maven framework for CI build. I am wondering if there is a way to reference websphere jars other than via dependencies in pom.xml and loading them all to maven repository? I cannot imagine loading them ALL to the repository...
Please advice! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

When using Maven, it is advisable that all dependent jars are installed in the repository. Even Websphere ones.

Ideally a corporate repository will come in handy here, so that you keep a separate repository for all the Websphere jars accessible to all the users in your project. See http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html for more.

If this is not an option, then use the **local file repository** [explained on a previous questions - here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path/2230464#2230464).

You'll still need to add each dependency in POM.

Also read http://sdudzin.blogspot.com/2007/09/maven-2-and-websphere-automated-build.html

Answer (score 1):

if you have a lot of projects that require this, you can also create a parent pom that would have all the dependencies so your project/module/portlet poms are cleaner.