# Using IDEA with maven2, how to add a non-maven .jar?

Tags: java, maven-2, intellij-idea

I have a .jar that I want included in my IDEA web application project that is using maven2 (pom.xml).

How can I add a .jar to my project that isn't using maven?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You basically have three options:

- Install the jar in your local repository using [`install:install-file`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) (see [Guide to installing 3rd party JARs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)). This is pretty straightforward and easy but this will make your POM non portable. This might be an option if you are alone and doesn't plan to distribute your pom.xml.
- Deploy the jar in a corporate repository using `deploy:deploy-file`. This is of course the ideal and preferred scenario in a corporate environment.
- If you're not using a corporate repository but are still working in team, [setup a file based repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path/2230464#2230464) and share it through  your source repository.

Answer (score 6):

Easiest thing is to use `maven:install-file` to install the jar in your local repository, as follows (stolen from [the docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/installing-secondary-artifacts.html):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=path-to-non-maven.jar \
                      -DgroupId=some-id \
                      -DartifactId=some-artifact \
                      -Dversion=some-version \
                      -Dpackaging=jar
```

Then add it to your POM like any other dependency. If it needs to be shared with many people, you may consider setting up a local instance of something like [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) or [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.org/products.php) (we use Artifactory where I work and it works well).

Answer (score 5):

Google addjars maven plugin is a good idea. This can be done through following steps:

1. Add all dependencies to `lib` folder codebase.
2. Add google addjars plugin to `<build>`

   ```
   <plugin>
           <groupId>com.googlecode.addjars-maven-plugin</groupId>
           <artifactId>addjars-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.0.5</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>add-jars</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <resources>
                           <resource>
                               <directory>${basedir}/lib</directory>
                           </resource>
                       </resources>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
   ```
3. `mvn compile` will now create a local repo and add all jars as dependencies. `mvn compile` will then work as charm.
4. To let idea resolve dependencies go to `module settings -> modules -> dependencies` add lib folder.

Reference: https://code.google.com/archive/p/addjars-maven-plugin/issues

Answer (score 0):

Trying to guess what the question is:

1) You have a maven project A with jar foo.jar 
2) You have a non-maven project B that you want to use the same jar in (without using maven)
3) You are on windows?

If this is true, then:

Go grab the jar from `c:\documents and settings\your_username\.m2\name_of_jar,` and stick it in the WEB-INF/lib directory of project B

Answer (score 0):

The maven install:install-file is perfect for adding a local JAR to your caches, but if you're using a repository externally (i.e. Archiva or Nexus), then you're better off making it available to all with "mvn deploy:deploy-file" - similar arguments for that command.

Installing just locally means that if you purge your local cache for whatever reason (i've ended up doing this a number of times to solve this or that problem with corrupted local cache), then you loose the local JAR as well and need to remember to re-add it again. If it's in the local DSL repository through Nexus or Archiva, you're in good shape - just add the resulting groupId, artifactId into the POM and carry on.