# How to create a Maven Artifact, from lonely *.jar files?

Tags: eclipse, svn, maven-2, jar

I'm using Eclipse to manage my SVN repository, and I have a few projects that depend on the same Jar files, I would like to create a maven artifact of these Jars (if possible using Eclipse) and commit that artifact into my SVN repository for further use.
How can I achieve that?

Thanks,
Adam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mvn install:install-file did the trick:
[Install-File](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html)

Answer (score 2):

Create an Eclipse project which contains all the JARs and an ANT `build.xml` which calls `mvn file:install` for each JAR to install then in your local Maven repository ([see the docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html) for options of `mvn file:install`).

That way, you can use these JARs like any other Maven dependency after running the `build.xml` once.

[EDIT] A sample target would look like this:

```
<target name="maven-file-install">
  <exec executable="mvn"> <!-- Make sure mvn is in the PATH -->
    <arg value="file:install"/>
    <arg value="-Dfile=your-artifact-1.0.jar"/>
    ... all the other arguments of file:install ...
  </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: I do understand what I need to do, but I have never used maven in the XML form, so I actually don't know hoe the build.xml should look like, could you add a short example please, I'm sure I'll be able to take it from there... Thanks.

Comment: It's really simple; I've added an example.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a file based repository:

- Create a module containing a *file based repository*
- Install the jars in this file based repository
- Commit the module to SVN

Detailed steps are provided in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path/2230464#2230464).

#### Similar questions

- [Maven: add a dependency to a jar by relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path/)

Comment: When you say module you refer to the folder containing the "maven-metadata-local.xml" that was generated?

Comment: I also need to add native library, is it possible?

Comment: @TacB0sS: No, I mean a maven project.