# Maven Dependencies

Tags: maven-2

I am trying build a jar file with some dependencies. Initially i have installed all the jar file dependencies with mvn install:install-file command. Now Instead of that i given as below.

```
 < dependency>
        < groupId> POP< /groupId>
        < artifactId>ROCK< /artifactId>
        < version>1< /version>
        < scope>system< /scope>
        < systemPath>../Environment/lib/jdk15-131.jar< /systemPath>
   < /dependency>
```

Now it does not relative path, It is asking for absolute path. Can you please suggest how can i give relative path?

Regards
Gnash

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
< systemPath>${basedir}/../Environment/lib/jdk15-131.jar< /systemPath>
```