# Using Maven without my own repository

Tags: maven

How would you collaborate on a Maven project with another developer, without setting up a repository on a dedicated server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another option: use a [file-based repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path/2230464#2230464) stored in your version control system and  install your few 3rd party jars into it.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- run a repository manager, e.g. Nexus on one of the developer's machines and all developers could use that repository
- everyone will have to rebuild required dependencies from the source code taken from version control system

Comment: That doesn't sound too sweet. Isn't there another way to resolve those few 3rd party jars that aren't uploaded to the main repository?