# How to declare jar file in pom.xml?

Tags: java, android, maven

What is the right declaration of local jar library in maven pom.xml?

I need this to add [bugsense-trace.jar](http://www.bugsense.com/docs/android) that is not present in maven central.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. There is a thing called 'system' scope, but it always causes more problems than it solves.

Use mvn install:install-file, or better yet install nexus or archiva and deploy it there.

Answer (score 2):

Install it in the local repository (or just place it under `com/foo/bar/0.1` in the local repository) and refer to it by that fqn.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path/2230464#2230464) for more details.