# import external jar in maven project without creating a dependency

Tags: java, maven, import, jar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Maven: add a dependency to a jar by relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path)

I need import a .jar file using only a buildpath in a java maven project without creating a dependency. Can this be done?

Comment: why want to import it, if not dependent?

Comment: If you don't want to use that in your packing, you can set the scope as provided in POM.

Answer (score 2):

You mean that your jar is used only to compile but is not a *transitive* dependency?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**provided**:
 This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

See more on [dependency scopes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)