# spark 0.9.1 on hadoop 2.2.0 maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, apache-spark

I set up Apache Spark maven dependency in pom.xml as follows

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I found that this dependency use "**hadoop-client-1.0.4.jar**" and "**hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar**", and when I run my program I got the error "**org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4**", which shows that I need to switch hadoop version from 1.0.4 to 2.2.0.

**Updates**:

Is the following solution a correct method to solve this problem?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion> 
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion> 
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions> 
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, your solution is fine, and the exclusion of `hadoop-client` is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark 1.2.0 depends on hadoop 2.2.0 be default.
If you can update your spark dependency to 1.2.0 (or newer) that will solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Recompile Spark for your Hadoop version, see "A Note About Hadoop Versions" here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.1/ . They conveniently give an example for 2.2.0

```
SPARK_HADOOP_VERSION=2.2.0 sbt/sbt assembly
```

This will create a new jar, `$SPARK_HOME/assembly/target/scala-2.10/spark-assembly-*jar` that you need to include into your pom.xml (instead of excluding Hadoop from the online jar).

If you're already hosting your own repository (e.g. on Nexus) then upload it there (this is what I do and it works great). If for some reason you can't upload to any repository, use Maven's `install:install-file` or one of the answers here [Maven: add a dependency to a jar by relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path)

Comment: I get the impression from the exchange with Matei at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1518 that he intended people to just update the `hadoop-client` dependency rather than make their own local Spark, but that also does something similar.