# Hadoop mismatch problems with spark?

Tags: scala, hadoop, sbt, apache-spark

I am trying to read from hdfs on hadoop 0.20 and am getting an error with client server mismatch. How do I get rid of this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [spark 0.9.1 on hadoop 2.2.0 maven dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23938633/spark-0-9-1-on-hadoop-2-2-0-maven-dependency)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark is only available on Hadoop 2, so not available with your 0.20.2