How to share the internal library of the plugin with the current IntelliJ IDEA project?
I am developing an IntelliJ IDEA Plugin that has an example.jar library as a dependency.
// build.gradle.kts
dependencies {
  implementation(files("src/main/resources/example.jar"))
}

So, I has built the plugin, started IDEA and created a new project. Can I import my example.jar library in this new project?
import myPlugin.example // something like that

Is it possible to import the internal dependency of a plugin in a new IDEA project?
Or how to add the necessary dependency when installing the plugin?

I didn't quite get you, is the example.jar a library? Do you mean you want to use this example.jar in a new plugin project? One thing you may try use a multi-module Gradle project https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html
Or install the jar to a local maven library, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798240/use-jar-as-intellij-maven-dependency
