# Maven external dependencies - Nexus not an option

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I have a Maven project which holds a number of shared classes for two other projects (one maven Java SE project and one Android project).

I need to package this shared jar up in the other projects when I do a build.

Now I know of Nexus, but I'm working without access to a shared installation of it.

Is the only option to include the shared jar as part of the maven/gradle projects in src/main/resources for example?

Comment: You could use maven local with your dependencies scope set to system. see it here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: Wasn't me. But I guess that it was because you didn't provide much more details like your project configurations.

Comment: Stackoverflow is awesome: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path

Comment: ok thanks, both of these comments kind of backup my assertion with a bit more detail

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is to host your own internal host repository. See [here](https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) for more details. We use [SonaType Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/go/).

However, you could just rely on your "local repo". When you do `mvn install`, the artifacts you build get hosted to your local filesystem, typically at `~/.m2/repository`. See your Maven [settings.xml](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) for the exact location.

So, if you always build your shared code first with `mvn clean install`, the shared artifacts will be available when you do `mvn clean install` in the projects that use it. Of course, this will mean that the artifacts are not published and remain local to your build server or local machine. This defeats somewhat the dependency management feature of Maven.

Comment: As I said Nexus isn't an option at the moment, and relying on the local filesystem isn't great as it's a shared project. I guess I'll just add the jar as managed resource in the git project as I mentioned

Comment: There are other options. See [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html). Note, as long as the file is accessible by URL, such as `file://` or `http://`, it doesn't really matter how you make the files available. You can use an ordinary web server or remote filesystem mount.

Comment: thanks that's useful, I'll keep it in mind, for the moment I've gone with the system scope dependency, I may revisit this later