# Maven: How to use a dependency that doesn't have it's own repo

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have one of my own custom projects that is an API. What I want to do with it is use it with another one of my projects, however I don't have a maven repository for it, so I cannot add it to the pom.xml for anyone to build

What do I need to do?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path  please check this

Comment: Why not just have the other project call your custom project through its API?

Comment: I think we are talking about a Java API, not a networked API (but even for that, you probably want to link against a client library).

Answer (score 1):

I would modify the API project to be built as a Maven project, then run a Maven install against it, this should push it into your local repository and you should be able to use it from the Maven project like any other.

If your company also has a repository that it stores its own code too, something like Nexus, you would do a Maven Release and this would push it to that repository.

Comment: Yes, "mvn install" is the best way. No weird setup at the consuming projects necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I've also found file system based repositories useful in situations like this.  You don't need to be running Nexus or Artifactory or anything you just need to make sure all users have access to a shared drive.

As an example:

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
   <id>local-files</id>
   <name>local-files</name>
   <url>file://S:\filerepo</url>
  </repository> 
<repositories>
```

Comment: First the given  url is not correct cause it should look like this: ` <url>file:///S:/filerepo</url>` furthermore you should prefer using a repository manager instead of file bases repositories...

Comment: I disagree but you are entitled to your opinion.

Comment: I never you knew you could do that.  Thanks