# How to package an artifact using existing dependency artifacts?

Tags: maven-3, maven-reactor

I have a simple project containing some WAR artifacts and one EAR artifact which bundles it together.

```
<modules>
    <module>service1</module>
    <module>service2</module>

    <module>ear</module>
</modules>
```

If I run `mvn package` with that pom it works fine. The reactor recognizes the artifacts and I don't have to use the local repository.

I want to build service1 and service2 seperatly. After that I want to build ear using the build results from service1 and service2.
If I run `mvn package` only for ear, it searches the artifacts in the local repository and it will fail, because there are not there.

How can I tell the ear plugin to look somewhere else e.g. the target folder of the modules itself?

*Background*: I want to build every feature branch and don't want to mess up my local repository nor duplicate it for every branch.

Comment: Did you try to use <relativePath> tag in the dependency list?

Comment: Is relativePath not only available for the parent POM?

Comment: You're probably right. Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path