# Maven dependency from local file - resolve any (*) symbol

Tags: java, maven, path, dependency-management

I want to use `missioncontrol` module which is not published at maven repository and is installed with JDK. I could manually install it by `mvn install` like it's done in [this script](https://github.com/chrishantha/jfr-flame-graph/blob/master/install-mc-jars.sh). But I'd prefer maven to resolve this dependency automatically.

The issue is I don't know exact version of module on each machine (assuming that `JAVA_HOME` is defined for every machine). And maven does not seem to automatically resolve the `*` placeholder:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jrockit.mc</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.jrockit.mc.common</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/missioncontrol/plugins/com.jrockit.mc.common_*.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Is there any proper way to do this? Or is it a bad practice for some reason? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path)

Comment: I have only jar's and not maven-metadata.xml files, so maven fails to download it

Answer (score 0):

Does your jar file name changes with java version

Comment: Yes, it depends on JDK version and it varies according to machine