# Maven Compilation Error: package does not exist - net.sourceforge.jpapi

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tycho

When I try to build my Maven project (via Eclipse) I get the error

> package net.sourceforge.jdpapi does not exist

I don't find the correct Maven dependency for that package. Does anyone know how to add that dependency? I cannot find it on https://mvnrepository.com/.

This is a part of the debug log:

```
/C:/Users/PhilipF/git8/QPM_AdminTool/de.dspace.qpm.admintool.auxiliary/src/de/dspace/qpm/admintool/auxiliary/ds/SecurePasswordGenerator.java:[6,50] com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.classfile.Code is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
[INFO] 1 warning
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/PhilipF/git8/QPM_AdminTool/de.dspace.qpm.admintool.auxiliary/src/de/dspace/qpm/admintool/auxiliary/ds/EncryptionManager.java:[15,30] package net.sourceforge.jdpapi does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/PhilipF/git8/QPM_AdminTool/de.dspace.qpm.admintool.auxiliary/src/de/dspace/qpm/admintool/auxiliary/ds/EncryptionManager.java:[58,23] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DataProtector
  location: class de.dspace.qpm.admintool.auxiliary.ds.EncryptionManager
[ERROR] /C:/Users/PhilipF/git8/QPM_AdminTool/de.dspace.qpm.admintool.auxiliary/src/de/dspace/qpm/admintool/auxiliary/ds/EncryptionManager.java:[71,38] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DataProtector
  location: class de.dspace.qpm.admintool.auxiliary.ds.EncryptionManager
[INFO] 3 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.672 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-26T15:18:47+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/193M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project de.dspace.qpm.admintool.auxiliary: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/PhilipF/git8/QPM_AdminTool/de.dspace.qpm.admintool.auxiliary/src/de/dspace/qpm/admintool/auxiliary/ds/EncryptionManager.java:[15,30] package net.sourceforge.jdpapi does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/PhilipF/git8/QPM_AdminTool/de.dspace.qpm.admintool.auxiliary/src/de/dspace/qpm/admintool/auxiliary/ds/EncryptionManager.java:[58,23] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class DataProtector
[ERROR] location: class de.dspace.qpm.admintool.auxiliary.ds.EncryptionManager
[ERROR] /C:/Users/PhilipF/git8/QPM_AdminTool/de.dspace.qpm.admintool.auxiliary/src/de/dspace/qpm/admintool/auxiliary/ds/EncryptionManager.java:[71,38] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class DataProtector
[ERROR] location: class de.dspace.qpm.admintool.auxiliary.ds.EncryptionManager
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project de.dspace.qpm.admintool.auxiliary: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1029)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

And this is may pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>de.dspace.qpm.admintool.auxiliary</groupId>
  <artifactId>de.dspace.qpm.admintool.auxiliary</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0 qualifier</version>
  <repositories>
            <repository>
               <id>eclipse-oxygen</id>
               <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen</url>
               <layout>p2</layout>
            </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.osgi/org.osgi.core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jasypt/jasypt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.messadmin/MessAdmin-Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.messadmin</groupId>
            <artifactId>MessAdmin-Core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: download it and provide it by yourself. its not in a public maven repo. https://sourceforge.net/projects/jdpapi/files/

Comment: The search result for Maven Central says something different: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cnet.sourceforge.messadmin

Comment: Download jar & then provide using the method provided in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path