# Issue connecting spring-boot to azure sql server

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, azure

I have a spring-boot project in which i try to connect to an azure sql database i just created. First time i tried it i was using sqljdbc4 under com.microsoft.sqlserver groupId, everytime i tried to launch it i had security errors, googling around i found out it's fixed by using 6+ versions. Then i installed it and set the dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>slqjdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now i don't have that error anymore but instead i have **org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver**

Dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>slqjdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

application.properties

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/console
spring.datasource.platform=h2

#  production profile
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://spring-boot-intro.database.windows.net:1433;database=spring-boot-intro;user=fabio@spring-boot-intro;password=*my password*;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
spring.datasource.username=fabio
spring.datasource.password=*my password*
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

#  crud
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

slqjdbc6 under .m2 repository

```
C:\Users\*user*\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\sqlserver\slqjdbc6\maven-metadata-local.xml
C:\Users\*user*\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\sqlserver\slqjdbc6\6\_remote.repositories
C:\Users\*user*\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\sqlserver\slqjdbc6\6\slqjdbc6-6.2.1.jar
C:\Users\*user*\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\sqlserver\slqjdbc6\6\slqjdbc6-6.2.1.pom
```

Answer (score 1):

To where did you install that driver? The SQL Server drivers are not available in public Maven Repositories, so unless you have a private maven repository to which you've added that dependency, including it in your `pom.xml` will not result in the jdbc driver being available at runtime.

If you do not have a private / corporate maven repository to add the JDBC driver to, I would suggest adding the jar file within your source code and using a `filesystem` repository to reference that file.

You can refer to this answer for additional details on how to create such a repository [Maven: add a dependency to a jar by relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path)

Comment: I had to manually install 'slqjdbc6' drivers. They are installed under 'C:\Users\*user*\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\sqlserver\slqjdbc6\6'. I've added the paths at the end of the post

Comment: That's not a very portable way to solve it, as each user will have to do that. But either way, note that the version you reference in your file:

    `<groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>`
    `<artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>`
    `<version>6.2.1.jre8</version>`

are not the same as you've put into your local repository.  Both the artifact and version do not match what you've put on your filesystem

Comment: Oh, i posted the wrong pom because i was using multiple windows. I edited with the correct one. It's taken correctly from netbeans because if i change anything, even just the version numbers it will show me the error **some dependency artifacts are not in the local repository** and won't let me run it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the two ways for resolving your issue.

1. As @Ben said, please refer to the section [`Using the JDBC Driver with Maven Central`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server#using-the-jdbc-driver-with-maven-central) of the document `Download Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server` to add the `mssql-jdbc` driver dependency into the `pom.xml` file and install it via Maven Central.
2. Or you can first download the jar file of MS SQL Server JDBC driver from the link of the above document. Then to run the command `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar -Dpackaging=jar -DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver -DartifactId=mssqljdbc6 -Dversion=6.2.1` to install the maven dependency manually to local maven path and add the dependency content below to `pom.xml`.

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
       <artifactId>mssqljdbc6</artifactId>
       <version>6.2.1</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
spring.datasource.platform=h2
```

to

```
spring.datasource.platform=mssql
```