# MulitModule project dependency management

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am working on the project with the project structure as

root
 lib
  xyz.jar
 modules
  module1
  module2
Now I want to include the xyz.jar in the module1 but owing to the multimodule structure of the project, I am not able to add the jar directly through maven.

I tried using

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.commonjava.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>directory-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>directories</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>highest-basedir</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <property>multi.module.project.root.dir</property>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

and then using

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.abc.com</groupId>
            <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${multi.module.project.root.dir}/lib/xyz.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

but throws error to specify absolute path of jar.
next I tried using the de

```
pendency management in parent pom  by specifying 
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.abc.com</groupId>
                <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>${pom.basedir}/lib/xyz.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency>
```

This resolves the dependency but I am not able to use the dependency in the child pom of module1

How can I solve this

Comment: Am I correct to understand that the `xyz` dependency is not a dependency published in a Maven repository nor installed in your local maven repository? It is only available as a jar that you store directly in the `lib` directory of your project?

Comment: @VictorNoël yes its not available in maven repo

Comment: Install that lib separately into your local repo (better start using a repository manager) and use it as dependency. Don't use system scope dependencies  cause they are deprecated...Where is this xyz.jar coming from ? From another Maven build ?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the [directory-maven-plugin](https://github.com/jdcasey/directory-maven-plugin) you are using explicitly says about the variables produced by the plugin:

> They will be useful ONLY IN PLUGIN CONFIGURATIONS, NOT DURING POM INTERPOLATION.

This means you cannot use it like what you are doing.

As an alternative, I would consider referring to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2230464/9046139).