# Setting local repository ID when installing POMs

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I need a local repository for my project for a JAR file not available via the Maven Central repository. I install my JAR using `mvn install:install-file …` as per http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html, using `-DlocalRepositoryPath` to indicate the path in my Git repository, and using `-DcreateChecksum` to create checksums.

This installs the JAR, generates a POM, and generates checksums for all the files. But interestingly it also creates a `maven-metadata-local.xml` file in the groupId directory. From http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.5/maven-repository-metadata/ I gather that `local` is the ID it is giving the local repository.

But in my POM (`mvn install:install-file` had no way of knowing) I use the ID `local-repo` for my repository:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>local-repo</id>
    <url>file:///${project.basedir}/repo</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Of course I could change my POM to use simply `<id>local</id>` to match the generated files, but I don't like to do things without understanding why I'm doing it. So maybe someone could tell me:

- Do I need the `maven-metadata-local.xml`? Does it serve a purpose?
- Does the `local` part need to match the repository ID I use in the POM?
- Does `mvn install:install-file` have a parameter to allow me to indicate the ID to use for the local repository (e.g. to generate `maven-metadata-local-repo.xml`, or must I manually rename the file afterwards?

Comment: have a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path

Comment: Does that question say anything about the repository ID?

Comment: I would recommend to install a repository manager and use this....this will solve your problem..

Comment: But who said I even had a problem? I had some questions. And whether I have a problem one of the questions! You evaded the questions altogether.

Comment: @GarretWilson Based on your post you have jar's you are using which are not in Central which you have to install via `mvn install:install-file`...this is an indicator for using a repository (not the only one) and your strange configuration to use a file based repository...and installing files into a git repository...

Comment: It does nothing to do with `Java`...

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need the maven-metadata-local.xml? Does it serve a purpose?

Depends of what you want to do, I suggest you to read this to understand the role of  maven-metadata-local.xml

http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.5/maven-repository-metadata/

> Does the local part need to match the repository ID I use in the POM?

No, id declared in pom is just for loggin purpose durring maven build, this will you explain the use of id :

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html

> Does mvn install:install-file have a parameter to allow me to indicate the ID to use for the local repository (e.g. to generate maven-metadata-local-repo.xml, or must I manually rename the file afterwards?

yes according to maven api guide here :

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: Your 3rd answer is wrong. There is ONLY ONE local repo (where dependencies get downloaded from "remote repos"), so there is NO id for selecting a local repo.

Comment: My answer is not about  to named the metadata file to use a custom name. But as answer in point 2 the id as only login purpose the repo is unique...

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need the maven-metadata-local.xml? Does it serve a purpose?

Yes, you need it.

That is the file created to store the information of the different versions/releases you have installed in that local repo.

For example, I have installed in a local repo:

- First, the release 0.2.0 of a jar file.
- Second, the 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.

The `maven-metadata-local.xml` gets updated accordingly:

```
$ ls -l
drwxrwxr-x. 2 4096 Jun 21 16:14 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
drwxrwxr-x. 2 4096 Jun 21 16:12 0.2.0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 349 Jun 21 16:14 maven-metadata-local.xml
-rw-rw-r--. 1 32 Jun 21 16:14 maven-metadata-local.xml.md5
-rw-rw-r--. 1 40 Jun 21 16:14 maven-metadata-local.xml.sha1
```

So that:

```
$ cat maven-metadata-local.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
[...]
  <versioning>
    <release>0.2.0</release>
    <versions>
      <version>0.2.0</version>
      <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20180621151442</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

> Does the local part need to match the repository ID I use in the POM?

No. It is for logging purposes (of course you need the URL is a valid repo).

```
Downloading from this-is-my-local-repo: file:///...
```

> Does `mvn install:install-file` have a parameter to allow me to indicate
>   the ID to use for the local repository (e.g. to generate
>   maven-metadata-local-repo.xml, or must I manually rename the file
>   afterwards?

No, you don't need to rename the file. That "-local" suffix means that the metadata information it has is "local" to that repo.

Just to make this clearer, as explained in http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.2/maven-repository-metadata/:

> The metadata file name is:
>
> - `maven-metadata.xml` in a remote repository,
> - `maven-metadata-<repo-id>.xml` in a local repository, ***for metadata from    a repository*** with repo-id identifier.

So when making a "mvn install", on the local repo used (the default one under `./m2/repository` folder or the one given in `-DlocalRepositoryPath`), the file created is `maven-metadata-local.xml` since it is a LOCAL repository.

Similarly, on your local repo you can see different `maven-metadata-<repo-id>.xml` so you can see ***which repo the artifact is from*** (example from my local repo, where I have a settings.xml identifying central repo, shared release repo, shared snapshots repo, etc...

`.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/maven-metadata-central.xml
.m2/repository/[...]/maven-metadata-snapshots.xml`

Summing up,

- There is ONLY ONE local repo, so no ID to select it on "install-file".
- Repo ID is for the different repos you may have (for example, a repo for releases named "my-releases", another for snapshots named "my snapshots"). That `repo-id` is used when deploying an artifact to it:

`mvn deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=my-repo::default::file:///home/jalopaba/my-repo`