# maven create executable jar package with spring boot parent

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, executable-jar

I need to make an executable jar package out of my application.

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.nws</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-signer</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>rest-signer</name>
    <description>rest wrapper for signing lib</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>-->
        <!--<scope>compile</scope>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <compress>false</compress>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <useUniqueVersions>false</useUniqueVersions>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.nws.restsigner.RestSignerApplication</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.addjars-maven-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>addjars-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-jars</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/lib</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- put your configurations here -->
                <minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I build package with: `mvn clean package -DskipTests=true`
and run it by `java -jar` i get this:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to get nested archive for entry BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-jersey-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchives(JarFileArchive.java:86)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.getClassPathArchives(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:70)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open nested jar file 'BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-jersey-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar'
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:256)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:241)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:103)
        ... 4 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open nested entry 'BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-jersey-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar'. It has been compressed and nested jar files must be stored without compression. Please check the mechanism used to create your executable jar file
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromFileEntry(JarFile.java:284)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromEntry(JarFile.java:264)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:252)
        ... 6 more
```

mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.0 (NON-CANONICAL_2018-11-06T03:14:22+01:00_root; 2018-11-06T03:14:22+01:00)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_192, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.20.0-arch1-1-arch", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

so what should I change in my packaging to be able to run this finally?

Answer (score 3):

[`spring-boot-maven-plugin`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html) creates executable jar by default. So, you don't have to create it manually.

Basically, it's enough to just have this in the `pom.xml`:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

If your usage require some custom configuration (e.g. setting main class), [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/maven-plugin/usage.html) you can find good documentation.

Comment: Indeed, I suspect some of the other plugins (addjars, shade) are causing the problem.

Comment: I need those plugins in order to include my custom lib in project. really I have found no other way. without that it won't even compile

Comment: and i have maven-jar-plugin in place just to be able to set compress=false but it's the same without it through.
.original build runs well

Comment: Usually, if you have some custom library you can package it and publish to maven repository (e.g. local or nexus). Then just add that library to the `dependencies` section.

Comment: Also, another variant: you can get rid off spring boot parent, and use [bom](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent). Then get rid of spring-boot-maven-plugin and package your project using other plugins.

Comment: @greengold https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path

Comment: @greengold If I understood you right, you want to build library. Then you actually should not make it executable. You need to package it as `jar` and publish to the maven repository (e.g. local one) - @Gimby comment is relevant here. After publishing, you can create simple Spring Boot app, that uses your library, and make it executable using `spring-boot-maven-plugin`. Also if you really build library - I wouldn't recommend to inherit it from spring boot parent, but rather use bom mechanism instead.

Comment: @Zgurskyi, no. this project includes my lib. this is is the exec. wrapper and it is based on spring boot.