# how to call javaBridge Main from java application

Tags: java, php-java-bridge

i have question about this

this is my main class
this is mycode

```
 import dxtr.mtapi.mt4.data.QuoteClient;
    import php.java.bridge.JavaBridge;
     public class Main {
        
            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                QuoteClient qc = new QuoteClient(12342, "xasd", "localhost", 9900);
                JavaBridge.main(args);
            }
        }
```

error when i run

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: php/java/bridge/JavaBridge
    at dxtr.main.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: php.java.bridge.JavaBridge
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 1 more
```

the JavaBridge are different jar. so i add from local like this one here my pom. why my code error at there ?

install

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
      <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
       <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Build-Jdk>${jdk.version}</Build-Jdk>
                <Implementation-Title>${project.name}</Implementation-Title>
                <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
                <Specification-Title>${project.name} Library</Specification-Title>
                <Specification-Version>${project.version}</Specification-Version>
                <Class-Path>libs/JavaBridge-1.0.0.jar</Class-Path>
            </manifestEntries>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>dxtr.mtapi.mt4.main.Main</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
                  <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
               </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>make-my-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>single</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

i have try using from this here my pom from example from here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path`
i have update my pom like that. but i still cannot run javaBridge in my code. how to run java bridge.jar from my code ?
here the picture when i have add to my code
[image: here the screenshot of javabridge]

so how to fix the problem ? it is i must add the code or something like what ?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhgTO.png): [[image]

i also have try using this

```
java -cp JavaBridge.jar:build Dxtr.main.Main
```

but i got error like :
Error: Could not find or load main class Dxtr.main.Main

so how to fix this problem when try to run JavaBridge.main

Comment: Put JavaBridge.jar on the classpath when you run your code. for example, `java -cp JavaBridge.jar:build com.foo.YourMainApp`.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path

Comment: any sample for running it or setup the pom ?

Comment: i have update from example from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path but still have an error

Comment: @rzwitserloot i have update the problem can you try to run step by step to fix it ?

Comment: i have try using this also java -cp JavaBridge.jar:build dxtr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
Error: Could not find or load main class dxtr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: @rzwitserloot i still got error when use your example. i have try use this java -cp JavaBridge.jar:build Dxtr.main.Main
Error: Could not find or load main class Dxtr.main.Main

Comment: so i have also use Dxtr.main.Main still nothing happens... can someone explain one by one ?

Comment: i also have use local repository like this  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>JavaBridge</id>
      <name>JavaBridges</name>
      <url>file://Users/fuad/JavaBridge.jar</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

Comment: Yes i also have try using Java -cp JavaBridge.jar:build dxtr.main.Main... By the can you explain where i run this commendline? In my apps or when i run my jar of dxtr.main.Main jar? Cc @matt

Comment: You claim you get an error when you run. Where are you "running" your program. Can you go to the folder with your pom.xml and type `mvn package`? Does that work for you.