# Add dependency of external jar to a NAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-nifi, maven-plugin, maven-nar-plugin

I have following project structure

```
nifi-basename-bundle  
    ├── nifi-basename-nar  
    │   └── pom.xml  
    ├── nifi-basename-processors  
    │   ├── pom.xml  
    |   ├── libs  
    |   |   └── xyz.jar
    │   └── src  
    │       ├── main  
    │       │   ├── java  
    │       │   │   └── org.apache.nifi.processors.basename  
    │       │   │       └── MyProcessor.java  
    │       │   └── resources  
    │       │       ├── META-INF  
    │       │       │   └── services  
    │       │               └── org.apache.nifi.processor.Processor  
    │       └── test  
    │           └── java  
    │               └── org.apache.nifi.processors.basename  
    │                   └── MyProcessorTest.java  
    └── pom.xml
```

My `nifi-basename-nar` project has a dependency of `nifi-basename-processors` project as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example.prj</groupId>
    <artifactId>nifi-basename-processors</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have added a dependency of an external jar in the pom.xml of `nifi-basename-processors` project like below and my custom processor is referring to classes in this jar:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example.prj</groupId>
    <artifactId>test1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/xyz.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Once I build the project using `maven clean install`, the nar generated under project `nifi-basename-nar` does not have the `xyz.jar` bundled inside it. Hence it throws `NoClassDefFoundError` and nifi cannot start when this custom nar is deployed in nifi.

What is the correct way to handle this requirement?

Comment: you specified the scope 'system' that means that library will be provided at runtime by jdk or system.

Comment: @daggett I need to have the external jars bundled in the NAR when its built. If not 'system' then what is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: very similar to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2230464/1276664