Inject a Maven plugin from a local JAR into projects
Say I have created my own Maven plugin that's stored locally as a JAR in some arbitrary directory, but not published to the local Maven repository. Is there a way, like via mvn command line options, to "inject" this plugin JAR into a Maven build / project that does not by itself already declare a dependency on that plugin?
If that's not directly possible in a single mvn CLI invocation that both injects the plugin JAR and executes a goal from that plugin, is it possible via a multi-step process? Like, I assume I could use the install-file goal from the maven-install-plugin plugin to first publish it to the local Maven repository, but what then? Can I then inject it to a Maven build / project via its coordinates instead of the path to the JAR?

what about defining your own local repo and add it to it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2230464/460557

also you probably saw this already but just in case: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html

(1) I will run mvn install:install-file -Dfile="your-plugin.jar" "-DgroupId=com.example" "-DartifactId=your-plugin" "-Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" "-Dpackaging=jar" "-DcreateChecksum=true" one time. (2)  please notice the different between   0.0.1-SNAPSHOT  with 0.0.1 , with SNAPSHOT or without SNAPSHOT, (3) If your plugin is still under development and will be continuously updated and released, please remember to add SNAPSHOT to the version number.

The question: but not published to the local Maven repository.. why ... ?

See below.

So this is the multi-stage process I came up with for now:
#!/bin/bash

POM_FILE=$1

# Pretent that the plugin is only available locally.
curl -o cyclonedx-maven-plugin.jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/cyclonedx/cyclonedx-maven-plugin/2.8.1/cyclonedx-maven-plugin-2.8.1.jar

# Install the plugin JAR to the local Maven repository in order to be able to refer to it via GAV coordinates.
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:3.1.3:install-file -Dfile=cyclonedx-maven-plugin.jar

# Run the plugin's "makeAggregateBom" goal on the provided POM file.
mvn org.cyclonedx:cyclonedx-maven-plugin:2.8.1:makeAggregateBom -f $POM_FILE

# Remove the downloaded plugin JAR.
rm cyclonedx-maven-plugin.jar

I'd still prefer to avoid the step of the deployment to the local Maven repository, but I don't see how I could refer to the plugin then.

I don't see how this situation can come up. I mean, if you build a Maven plugin, you surely publish it in a Maven repository, and then you can just reference it like any other plugin.

Why do so complictated..simply define it in your pom file bind it to the life cycle and you can simply run mvn verify... That's it.. no curl, no install-file and separate call mageAggregate required...

"you surely publish it in a Maven repository". No, I actually don't. It's a plugin that ships as a resource within an application, and the application dynamically extracts the plugin at runtime when it needs to analyze a Maven project.

"simply define it in your pom file". In my scenario I must not modify the POM file. It comes from a third-party project that is not under my control.

@sschuberth I'm curious: What kind of analysation of Maven projects do you do?

It's about Open Source license / security compliance of third-party software, see https://oss-review-toolkit.org/.
