# Add compiled java class to a maven project

Tags: maven-2

I received some **compiled** classes that I need to add to a project.

One solution I can think of is creating a jar with these files and manually uploading it to the repository. Obviously this will work. But I wonder if there is a more elegant solution. May be I can put them somehow under the project structure? So the files will be checked-in to the source control and it will easier to maintain their versions, etc.

Comment: There's nothing elegant about distributing unpackaged compiled classes in the first place, I'm afraid.

Comment: As Boris has implied, storing binary class files in a source control repository is a bad idea.

Comment: @Sean: I agree, but this is the given situation, quite new to me I must admit, but currently there is nothing I can do about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's my approach as per the comments on Boris' answer (after finding myself needing to use the same yesterday, but unable to find the link to the answer I'd used):

In your project directory, create a folder called `repo`, which we'll use as a folder based Maven repository.

Add the following file repository to your project `pom.xml`:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>file.repo</id>
        <url>file://${project.basedir}/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Package your classes as a jar, and deploy them to the file repository, with the following command:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file
-Durl=file:///absolute/path/to/your-project/repo \
-DrepositoryId=file.repo \
-Dfile=path-to-your.jar \
-DgroupId=some.external.project.group \
-DartifactId=the-artifact-name \
-Dversion=1.0 \
-Dpackaging=jar;
```

Following this you can just add a normal dependency on the jar in your project `pom.xml`, using the values for groupId, artifactId and version you passed above. You can then add the repo folder to SVN, and commit the changes to your `pom.xml`. Any developer checking out your project will now be able to use the same dependency without any effort.

Answer (score 2):

The first idea is way better then checking in binaries that you don't have control over. So, bundle binaries in a jar, version it and deploy it on the repository.

Comment: And if you're working together with others with whom you're not sharing a repository, and would therefore like to add the dependency to your SCM: consider creating a file-repository under the project-root, deploy your packaged dependency to that repository, reference the file repository in your project POM and add that the repository to revision control.

Comment: @Tim your comment deserves to be an additional answer.

Comment: Well, I cannot fully agree with you. In source control I have more control on what's going on.

Comment: Thanks both. If the solution is clear enough as it is I'll leave it as a comment: I found out about this method through StackOverflow as well, so you should be able to find on SO. If not I'll elaborate in an answer, as I can't find the myself link right now..