# How do I add dependencies for 3rd party jars in to an android-maven project

Tags: android, maven

How do I add dependencies for 3rd party jar files in maven for Android. Some jars are not available in maven central. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You add them in your pom.xml as such...

```
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
   <artifactId>android</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  .. add to here ..
 </dependencies>
```

you can look up the libs you want here http://search.maven.org/

If they are not available there you can download the source and install them to your local repo. Learn about the [Maven Lifecycle here.](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

If you have a precompiled jar you can try this solution; [Add compiled java class to a maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919256/add-compiled-java-class-to-a-maven-project)

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, some jars arent available in Maven central. And to add the jar to local repo, there has to be a pom.xml included with the jar, which is not available.

Comment: The pom.xml comes with the source. What jar's do you need? Can you list them?

Comment: Its a library provided by the client. The name is gpm-crypto. Sorry to say cant provide you the jar.

Comment: Resolved. I created the pom file manually, added to the jar and installed in my local repo. Thanks

Comment: Great! if you think I helped you could accept and/or upvote. You get points for accepting an answer.