# Installing 3rd party JARs within Maven lifecycle vs system scoped dependency

Tags: java, maven-2

My project depends on some 3rd-party JARs which are not available in Maven Central.

Most information I see regarding this situation, including the official Maven [Guide to installing 3rd party JARs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html), advises installing the artifact into the local repository using `mvn install:install-file ...`. This works well when developing locally, but when the build needs to be performed on many different systems in an automated fashion, requiring this manual step is undesirable and impractical.

Another solution often presented is to install the dependency into an organization-wide repository, however there are circumstances in which that isn't possible.

With neither of those options being acceptable, I can think of two options:

1. Store the JAR in a lib directory within the project and declare the dependency with a `system` scope (as suggested in [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364114/can-i-add-jars-to-maven-2-build-classpath-without-installing-them/364188#364188) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396245/add-a-dependency-in-maven/765032#765032)). This would seem to work on any system since the dependency is bundled with the project, but I've seen the use of `system` discouraged as a bad practice (typically with no more explanation than that).
2. Bind the maven-install-plugin to the `initialize` lifecycle phase to install the artifact to the local repository. However, as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571022/is-it-best-to-mavenize-your-project-jar-files-or-put-them-in-web-inf-lib/6592613#6592613), this would cause unnecessary overhead as it runs for each and every build. If there were a way to execute this lazily only when the artifact is not installed, that might be ideal.

I would like a standard Maven project that can be built using the regular Maven lifecycle, without any out-of-band "run scripts/init-dependencies first" steps required.

What is the best way forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recent answer to that question: [Maven: keeping dependent jars in project version control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301156/maven-keeping-dependent-jars-in-project-version-control/5305044#5305044)

I do not recommend using install-file in the lifecycle. As you've mentioned, it will run every time - the above solution will skip through the project quite quickly. While the above creates a new module, it does reduce the verbosity needed for many JARs, allows you to use a repository format that can easily be copied into a repository manager, and keeps this out of your main build.

I also do not recommend using system scope for the reasons mentioned some answers to the questions you linked to list.

Answer (score 1):

I would create an ant task to check for a .mylibisinstalled file. If it doesn't exist, mvn install yourlib.jar and create it.

You can then associate this ant task with the initialize phase of maven - the overhead would be minimal.

It's a bit hackish, but you do have some constraints.

Answer (score 0):

> If there were a way to execute this lazily only when the artifact is
>   not installed, that might be ideal.

I will give a straight answer to your question even knowing of it's inherent ugliness. I've been using a workaround recipe with success for a while, but be warned that personally I don't think this is any better than system dependencies. Maven people consider abusing profiles a bad practice.

Create a separate [profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) to install the libs and bind the `maven-install-plugin` as proposed in your question.

You could activate the profile manually with `-P myprofile`.
Another option if you feel like going 100% hackish, is adapting @vlf "check for file" suggestion to pure Maven. Just use a activation trigger for the profile.
Maybe something like this (**WARNING**: untested):

```
<activation>
  <file>
    <missing>${user.home}/.myapp/.mylibisinstalled</missing>
  </file>
</activation>
```

If you have a common set of libraries that are used by many projects, just create a separate *installer* artifact with it's own pom.xml. This way you don't need to carry the same jar files for multiple projects.

I personally have a `install-extra-libs` artifact with this purpose. It has some jar files in a lib folder (and also some jars of javadocs and source code), some dependencies to obscure / password protected repositories, and even download some files directly using [antrun:run](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/run-mojo.html) and ANT [get task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html). For the lib folder and downloaded jars, there're some massive`install-file` bidings. It is ugly and hackish but works when you commonly needs to install the same set of libraries / javadocs over and over again into multiple repositories.

**PROS:**

- All the hackery happens inside this artifact. My projects uses clean dependency syntax.
- No jar files duplication. No JAR files in SCM.
- I consider it a way to create new Maven repositories "on the fly".

**CONS:**

- It defeats Maven purpose. If you find yourself doing it for public open source projects, consider uploading it to a public repository and syncing with the Maven Central... Here's a [guide](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide) explaining how to do that from Sonatype repository. It takes some time, but at least other people may benefit from your effort.
- It defeats Maven purpose x2. If you don't be careful, soon you lose track of which dependencies are on Central Repository. Most of my projects uses one or more custom installed dependencies, making any of then public would be a pain.

Cheers,