# Missing of added jars to maven builth classpath via static in-project repository solution

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

One of the best strategies recommended for adding of JARs files in maven's project with no public repository is using of static in-project repository. Nice blog : http://charlie.cu.cc/2012/06/how-add-external-libraries-maven/ or one of the most popular as I found StackOverflow posts [Can I add jars to maven 2 build classpath without installing them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364114/can-i-add-jars-to-maven-2-build-classpath-without-installing-them) 
Does someone have had next issue when make totally same steps for integrating of the solution (my particular case is adding of filters-1.0.jar file): "Missing artifact imageUtil:filters:jar:0.1:compile" or in other words, nevertheless the static in-project repository is set up in pom.xml at the end also could not be recognized ? Does something is missed by me ?

Here are my steps integrating of the solution:

- create a "repo" folder in root of my maven project
- in pom.xml I registered static in-repository :

> `<repository>`
>
> ```
>        <id>repo</id>
>        <releases>
>            <enabled>true</enabled>
>            <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
>        </releases>
>        <snapshots>
>            <enabled>false</enabled>
>        </snapshots>
>        <url>file://${project.basedir}/repo</url>
> ```
>
> `</repository>`

- Again in pom.xml added mention dependency :

> `<dependency>`
>
> ```
>   <groupId>imageUtil</groupId>
>   <artifactId>filters</artifactId>
>   <version>0.1</version>
> ```
>
> `</dependency>`

- last step is copy-pacing of mention JAR in next sub-folder structure

  /repo/imageUtil/filters/0.1/filters-0.1.jar

When I checked in buildpath for the project (I am using Eclipse) I also saw that mention JAR is looking in my local repository  or 
 - /home/simeon/.m2/repository/imageUtil/filters/0.1 (missing)

Maybe the question here is "how to say to my maven project that this JAR should be searched in my static in-project repository" ?

Thanks in advance, 
SImeon

Comment: maybe it's too late, but when first time running maven, do a `mvn install -U` so it force updates all dependencies and puts to local repo and then in Eclipse right click on your project `Maven` > `Update Project...`

Answer (score 2):

Your settings look fine. Is it never taking your in-project repository or do you mean it works first time and after that it will look only in the `/home/simeon/.m2/repository/imageUtil/filters/0.1`

I tried something similar and saw that *if I give the name of a standard library which is available in a Maven Central repository, it looks there first and downloads it from there*.

So I took a standard library (saxon) and renamed it to something different (eg: saxonic) which I know will not be available in any external repo, and I can see it uses my defined *"inprojrepo"* and installs this into my own local maven repository.

After that it uses from the local maven repository for next build.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: file://D:\mymavenproject\someproject/inprojrepo/net/sf/Saxo
nic/9.4/Saxonic-9.4.pom
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/sf/Saxonic/9.4/Saxonic-9.4.
pom
[WARNING] The POM for net.sf:Saxonic:jar:9.4 is missing, no dependency informati
on available
Downloading: file://D:\mymavenproject\someproject/inprojrepo/net/sf/Saxo
nic/9.4/Saxonic-9.4.jar
Downloaded: file://D:\mymavenproject\someproject/inprojrepo/net/sf/Saxon
ic/9.4/Saxonic-9.4.jar (9560 KB at 29234.1 KB/sec)
[INFO]
```

My POM

```
<repository>
    <id>inprojrepo</id>
    <releases>
           <enabled>true</enabled>
           <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
       </releases>
       <snapshots>
           <enabled>false</enabled>
       </snapshots>
    <url>file://${project.basedir}/inprojrepo</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: Hi Jose, 
Thanks for the recommendation, but another issue appeared applying it - all JARs taken from the public repository are now marked as missing : 
    Missing artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
    Missing artifact org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.19:compile
..... and so on 
Regarding the JAR, local one, with changed name - no information about it. DId you have such kind of issues when you start with implementration of name changing strategy ?

Comment: @SimeonAngelov: Nope nothing like that - which version of Maven? I am using apache-maven-3.0.4-bin

Comment: At the end I used other strategy: first I install all local JARs (in a parent) and then I use them as normal dependences. Cheers, Simeon