# adding a jar to reference library

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I have a jar file I could attach it to project reference library, but it does not have META-INF folder. Does attaching a jar by configuring build path still works?

Comment: *"Does attaching a jar by configuring build path still works?"*  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Is this an Eclipse question?

Comment: I attached it and tried adding it in pom in eclipse, but it is not able to recognize the dependency.

Comment: Are you using maven ? Then this previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364114/can-i-add-jars-to-maven-2-build-classpath-without-installing-them will prove to be useful

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about Eclipse, yes, a .jar file without a META-INF folder works on the build path of a project. I just tried it.