# Cannot run Arquillian test case on Glassfish

Tags: maven, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I am stuck very badly in a very simple implementation of an Arquillian test case. I followed [Can I add jars to maven 2 build classpath without installing them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364114/can-i-add-jars-to-maven-2-build-classpath-without-installing-them/7623805#7623805) to add my project jars to maven repository. I am using Glassfish server as my application server.
Then I need to write arquillian test cases.
For that I used the following code

```
@Inject
   private ControllerLoginModule controllerloginmodule;
    @Deployment
   public static WebArchive createDeployment()
   {
     File[] lib = Maven.resolver()
            .resolve("com.controllerjars:controllerbeans:1.0.0","com.controllerjars:controllerapi:2.0.0","com.controllerjars:controllerauth:1.0.0")
            .withTransitivity().as(File.class);

    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
            .addClasses(ControllerLoginModule.class,AuthRealm.class,IAccountManagerInternal.class)
            .addAsLibraries(lib)
            .addAsWebInfResource(new StringAsset("<beans/>"), "beans.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource(new StringAsset("<web-app></web-app>"), "web.xml");

   }  
@Test
   public void testIsDeployed()
   {
      Assert.assertNotNull(controllerloginmodule);

   }
```

Basically I am loading some jars which contains Classes Under Test and the classes on which those classes depends. In the end I am trying to create a web archive out of it. 
Then I try to test that wether object is null or not.

The issue which I can figure out from the stack trace is the deployment is not able to find the files from Maven. Below is the stack trace observed when I try to run the test case.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke deployment method: public static org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive com.appdynamics.auth.ControllerLoginModuleTest.createDeployment()
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.invoke(AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.java:160)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.generateDeployment(AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.generate(AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.java:57)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.DeploymentGenerator.generateDeployment(DeploymentGenerator.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:182)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:199)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.invoke(AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.java:156)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new descriptor instance
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.DependencyBuilderInstantiator.createFromUserView(DependencyBuilderInstantiator.java:101)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.DependencyResolvers.use(DependencyResolvers.java:39)
    at com.appdynamics.auth.ControllerLoginModuleTest.createDeployment(ControllerLoginModuleTest.java:51)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.DependencyBuilderInstantiator.createFromUserView(DependencyBuilderInstantiator.java:96)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.MavenRepositorySystem.getRepositorySystem(MavenRepositorySystem.java:220)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.MavenRepositorySystem.<init>(MavenRepositorySystem.java:64)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.MavenBuilderImpl.<init>(MavenBuilderImpl.java:105)
    ... 62 more
```

I can't understand where and what I am missing. I have updated the entries for dependencies given in the [Can I add jars to maven 2 build classpath without installing them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364114/can-i-add-jars-to-maven-2-build-classpath-without-installing-them/7623805#7623805). Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Below is my pom

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

   <!-- Model Information -->
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <!-- Artifact Information -->
  <groupId>com.auth</groupId>
  <artifactId>controller.functionaltest</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<!-- Properties -->
<properties>
  <version.shrinkwrap.resolver>2.0.0-beta-2</version.shrinkwrap.resolver>
  <version.junit>4.11</version.junit>
  <version.arquillian_core>1.0.3.Final</version.arquillian_core>
  <project.basedir>/controller.functionaltest</project.basedir>
  <version.org.jboss.shrinkwrap>1.1.2</version.org.jboss.shrinkwrap>
</properties>

<!-- Dependency Management -->
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
  <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-bom</artifactId>
  <version>${version.shrinkwrap.resolver}</version>
  <scope>import</scope>
  <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
  <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
  <version>${version.arquillian_core}</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<!-- Dependencies -->
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>${version.junit}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
  <version>${version.arquillian_core}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.controllerjars</groupId>
  <artifactId>commonscollections</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.controllerjars</groupId>
  <artifactId>commonutil</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.controllerjars</groupId>
  <artifactId>controllerapi</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.controllerjars</groupId>
  <artifactId>controllerauth</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.controllerjars</groupId>
  <artifactId>controllerbeans</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  </dependency>

 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-depchain</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <version>2.0.0-beta-2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<!-- Repositories -->
<repositories>
  <repository>
  <id>JBOSS_NEXUS</id>
  <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
  </repository>
  <repository>
  <releases>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
  </releases>
  <snapshots>
  <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
  <id>repo</id>
  <url>file://${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<!-- Plugin Configuration -->
<build>
  <finalName>controller.functionaltest</finalName>

  <!-- Compiler -->
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
  <configuration>
  <source>1.6</source>
  <target>1.6</target>
  <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
  </configuration>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>

  <!-- Plugin Management -->
  <pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
  <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings
  only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
  <plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
  <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <configuration>
  <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
  <pluginExecutions>
  <pluginExecution>
  <pluginExecutionFilter>
  <groupId>
  org.apache.maven.plugins
  </groupId>
  <artifactId>
  maven-dependency-plugin
  </artifactId>
  <versionRange>[2.1,)</versionRange>
  <goals>
  <goal>unpack</goal>
  </goals>
  </pluginExecutionFilter>
  <action>
  <ignore></ignore>
  </action>
  </pluginExecution>
  </pluginExecutions>
  </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
  </configuration>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
<profiles>
  <profile>
  <id>GLASSFISH_REMOTE_3.1_(REST)</id>
  <build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <extensions>false</extensions>
  <executions>
  <execution>
  <id>unpack</id>
  <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
  <goals>
  <goal>unpack</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
  <artifactItems>
  <artifactItem>
  <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-as-dist</artifactId>
  <version>7.1.3.Final</version>
  <type>zip</type>
  <overWrite>false</overWrite>
  <outputDirectory>~/JBOSS_Managed</outputDirectory>
  </artifactItem>
  </artifactItems>
  </configuration>
  </execution>
  </executions>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>

  </build>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
  <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-remote-3.1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  </profile>
  <profile>
  <id>JBOSS_AS_MANAGED_7.X</id>
  <build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <extensions>false</extensions>
  <executions>
  <execution>
  <id>unpack</id>
  <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
  <goals>
  <goal>unpack</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
  <artifactItems>
  <artifactItem>
  <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-as-dist</artifactId>
  <version>7.1.3.Final</version>
  <type>zip</type>
  <overWrite>false</overWrite>
  <outputDirectory>~/JBOSS_Managed</outputDirectory>
  </artifactItem>
  </artifactItems>
  </configuration>
  </execution>
  </executions>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>

  </build>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
  <version>7.1.3.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  </profile>
</profiles>
</project>
```

below is my Dependency tree .

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building controller.functionaltest 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ controller.functionaltest ---
[INFO] com.appdynamics.auth:controller.functionaltest:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:pom:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.resource:jboss-connector-api_1.5_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb:jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.el:jboss-el-api_2.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor:jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.security.jacc:jboss-jacc-api_1.4_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.enterprise.deploy:jboss-jad-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.security.auth.message:jboss-jaspi-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.registry:jboss-jaxr-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.jms:jboss-jms-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jsp:jboss-jsp-api_2.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind:jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.rpc:jboss-jaxrpc-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.soap:jboss-saaj-api_1.3_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.ws:jboss-jaxws-api_2.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.0-SP4:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.0.3-b05:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.jws:jsr181-api:jar:1.0-MR1:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:jaxrs-api:jar:2.1.0.GA:provided
[INFO] |  +- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:provided
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test (scope not updated to runtime)
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-core:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-api:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-api:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-spi:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-spi:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-api:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-spi:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-spi:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base:jar:2.0.0-alpha-3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.core:arquillian-core-impl-base:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.test:arquillian-test-impl-base:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-impl-base:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-api:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.arquillian.config:arquillian-config-impl-base:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi:jar:2.0.0-alpha-3:test
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-impl-base:jar:1.0.3.Final:test
[INFO] +- com.controllerjars:commonscollections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.controllerjars:commonutil:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.controllerjars:controllerapi:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.controllerjars:controllerauth:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.controllerjars:controllerbeans:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-depchain:pom:2.0.0-beta-2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-api:jar:2.0.0-beta-2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-spi:jar:2.0.0-beta-2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven:jar:2.0.0-beta-2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven:jar:2.0.0-beta-2:runtime
[INFO]    |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-api:jar:1.13.1:runtime
[INFO]    |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-impl:jar:1.13.1:runtime
[INFO]    |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-spi:jar:1.13.1:runtime
[INFO]    |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:jar:1.13.1:runtime
[INFO]    |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-connector-wagon:jar:1.13.1:runtime
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:jar:3.0.4:runtime
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0.4:runtime
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.0.4:runtime
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.0.4:runtime
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.0.4:runtime
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.0.4:runtime
[INFO]    |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.14:runtime
[INFO]    |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.6:runtime
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:2.2:runtime
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-file:jar:2.2:runtime
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-lightweight:jar:2.2:runtime
[INFO]    |     \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-shared4:jar:2.2:runtime
[INFO]    |        +- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.6.1:runtime
[INFO]    |        +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.2:runtime
[INFO]    |        \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.0.1:runtime
[INFO]    \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven-archive:jar:2.0.0-beta-2:runtime
[INFO]       +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-impl-base:jar:1.0.1:runtime
[INFO]       |  +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-api:jar:1.0.1:runtime
[INFO]       |  \- org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-spi:jar:1.0.1:runtime
[INFO]       +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven-archive:jar:2.0.0-beta-2:runtime
[INFO]       +- org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-spi-maven-archive:jar:2.0.0-beta-2:runtime
[INFO]       +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-javac:jar:2.1:runtime
[INFO]       |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar:2.1:runtime
[INFO]       \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-api:jar:1.0-alpha-33:runtime
[INFO]          \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:1.2-alpha-10:runtime
```

Comment: This exception looks more like your test classpath entries do not contain the required dependencies for the ShrinkWrap Maven Resolver. Can you post your POM?

Answer (score 2):

I think the cause of this problem is due to ambiguous ShrinkWrap Resolver dependencies. You should declare the ShrinkWrap Resolver Bill of Materials in the dependency Management chain before the Arquillian BOM. I recommend using the ShrinkWrap Resolver 2.0.0-beta-2.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-beta-2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${arquillian.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

In the dependency section you need to have the following dependencies present:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
    <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-depchain</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
    <version>2.0.0-beta-2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
    <version>${arquillian.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

The ShrinkWrap Resolver 2.0.0-beta-2 provides a new API for resolving artifacts, so you need to make sure you use that particular API, such as:

```
File lib = Maven.resolver()
        .resolve("artifact-groupid:artifact-artifactid:version")
        .withoutTransitivity()
        .asSingle(File.class);
return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
        .addClass(MyClass.class)
        .addAsLibrary(lib)
        .addAsWebInfResource(new StringAsset("<beans/>"), "beans.xml")
        .addAsWebInfResource(new StringAsset("<web-app></web-app>"), "web.xml");
```

I've created an example project containing the bare minimums needed to make use of ShrinkWrap Resolver which makes use of the configuration and code above, however running in an embedded TomEE container. You can find it here: https://github.com/tommysdk/showcase/tree/master/arquillian-shrinkres. Hopefully this can help you to straight out the correct dependencies and versions needed.

Comment: Thanks Tommy. I updated the code according to this. I edited my question  to include dependency tree, If that is of any help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The reason was that a resource file could not be reached. Example:

```
.addAsWebResource("index.html")
```

*Index.html* file must be in classpath during the test runtime or else the exception that throws is (!):

*java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke deployment method: public static org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.Archive com.intrasoft.ssp.persistence.admin.service.IndexPageTest.createDeployment()*

Comment: how did you debug / find this fix?

Answer (score 0):

Your POM looks like it is lending to a conflict or missing dependency among the ShrinkWrap artifacts pulled in by Arquillian BOM and the ShrinkWrap Resolvers depchain.

Going by [the POM snippet here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToIAddMavenArtifactsToMyShrinkWrapArchives), I believe you should also add the ShrinkWrap Resolver BOM as a managed dependency, before the Arquillian BOM, in your project POM.

Comment: Yeah I refered the same POM snippet. But the problem with that was as soon as i add the ShrinkWrap Resolver BOM before Arquillian BOM , It gives me compile error on DependencyResolvers.use(MavenDependencyResolver.class) saying DependencyResolvers cannot be resolved. I was just wondering that in this pom snippet it is also said to " <!-- Now pull in our server-based unit testing framework -->" .. Does that mean to add junit or testng dependencies. Also, In the dependency section does the order in which i add dependencies matters. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I checked the imports, It is giving compile errors as follows    The import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.DependencyResolvers cannot be resolved && The import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.maven.MavenDependencyResolver cannot be resolved

Comment: @user1020308 Well the Arquillian BOM pulls in ShrinkWrap v1.1 dependencies, so placing ShrinkWrap BOM above it in the dependencyManagement section is necessary and sufficient.

Comment: And as far as your compilation errors are concerned, you may want to switch to using the Resolvers class. Note that the APIs are still in flux, so they're subject to change. Examples on how to use this can be found in the tests: https://github.com/shrinkwrap/resolver/blob/master/impl-maven/src/test/java/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/resolver/impl/maven/integration/DependenciesUnitTestCase.java#L79

Comment: Thanks for quick replies.I did that. I was able to remove the compile time errors. But no luck with  ' Could not invoke deployment method:' error. Any further help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user1020308 Can you update your question with the Maven dependency tree. You can run `mvn dependency:tree` to get this info.