# Adding db2 jars to java webapp using maven

Tags: maven

I'm trying to add the following db2 jars to my Java web application using Maven...

```
db2jcc_license_cu.jar  
db2jcc_javax.jar   
db2jcc.jar
```

I'm following the instructions posted in this post...
[Can I add jars to maven 2 build classpath without installing them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364114/can-i-add-jars-to-maven-2-build-classpath-without-installing-them)

I want to use the static in-project repository solution. So far I have...

1. Created a folder in my root directory named lib. Inside this
   directory lives the three db2 jars.
2. Added the following to my pom file...

> ```
>  <repository>
>         <id>lib</id>
>         <releases>
>             <enabled>true</enabled>
>             <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
>         </releases>
>         <snapshots>
>             <enabled>false</enabled>
>         </snapshots>
>         <url>file://${project.basedir}/lib</url>    
>  </repository> 
>  </repositories>
> ```

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
    <artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.47</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
    <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cu</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.47</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I run a maven install I get ...

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.ibm.db2.jcc:db2jcc:jar:3.8.47 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.ibm.db2.jcc:db2jcc_license_cu:jar:3.8.47 is missing, no dependency information available
```

I got the version of the Jars by running a...

> java com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -version

Have I specified this version info corretly? Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can describe more precisely the folder hierarchy (if any) you have under ${project.basedir}/lib ?

Comment: Hi. I have no folder hierarchy under lib except the jars. The instructions in the post above say something about x.y.z . That bit confused me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't install the jars properly in your "project-maven-repository" (i.e. in the folder `${project.basedir}/lib`)

Maven stores (when you do `mvn install`) the jar files in a maven repository. A maven repository have precise hierarchical structure. Here is a simplified vision of this structure:

- the artifact `groupId`+`artifactId` define the first part of folder path (in the repository) where the artifact is stored.
- the artifact `version` is the second part of the folder path
- the artifact `version` is also a suffix to the artifact name
- the `artifactId` is the artifact name
- the packaging is the artifact extension (default is jar)

By default maven use a repository located under `<USER_HOME>/.m2/repository`

The solution you are trying to setup use another location for the repository : `${project.basedir}/lib` and even if it is not the default repository location it is still a *maven-repository* and so maven is expecting to find the usual maven repository hierarchy under this location.

That's why you need to organize your `${project.basedir}/lib` folder just like a maven repository. That's explained in this part of the [referenced post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364114/can-i-add-jars-to-maven-2-build-classpath-without-installing-them):

> **Use Maven to install to project repo**
>
> Instead of creating this structure by hand I recommend to use a Maven plugin to install your jars as artifacts. So, to install an artifact to an in-project repository under repo folder execute:
>
> `mvn install:install-file -DlocalRepositoryPath=lib -DcreateChecksum=true -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=[your-jar] -DgroupId=[...] -DartifactId=[...] -Dversion=[...]`
>
> If you'll choose this approach you'll be able to simplify the repository declaration in pom to:

```
<repository>
    <id>repo</id>
    <url>file://${project.basedir}/lib</url>
</repository>
```

So you need to do an `mvn install` to create the `${project.basedir}/lib` hierarchy (you can do it by hand, but it's not recommended and error prone).

I your case, the commands to run will be like this: (assuming you put the jar in your HOME_DIR and run this command in your `${project.basedir}`)

`mvn install:install-file -DlocalRepositoryPath=lib -DcreateChecksum=true -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=<USER_HOME>/db2jcc_license_cu.jar -DgroupId=com.ibm.db2.jcc -DartifactId=db2jcc_license_cu -Dversion=3.8.47`

What are the advantages of the approch you choose :

- a developer with no maven setup will have the libraries available inside the project sources, under SCM system.
- you can easily reference jars that aren't in a public maven repository without the need of something like [artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) or [nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/)

The drawbacks :

- a quite complex folder structure under `${project.basedir}/lib` looking very strange for someone not used to work with maven.
- you will store the libraries under SCM (lot's of huge binary files)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be to download those jars before hand and put them somewhere relatively to your project (like `lib` directory). Now just tell maven to use those jars. Here the `groupId`, `artifactdId` and `version` are JFYI since they won't be used to download anything.

The merit of this solution is that you won't have to build a maven repository.

```
<dependencies>
    ...      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
        <artifactId>licences</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version> <!-- Adjust this properly -->
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/db2jcc_license_cu.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version> <!-- Adjust this properly -->
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/db2jcc4.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc_javax</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version> <!-- Adjust this properly -->
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/db2jcc_javax.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Refer Link (Japanese): [Mavenリポジトリで提供されていないサードパーティJarをどうするか](http://sinsengumi.net/blog/2012/12/maven%E3%83%AA%E3%83%9D%E3%82%B8%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%81%A7%E6%8F%90%E4%BE%9B%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3jar/)

Answer (score 1):

I guess these jars do not have a pom.xml.  Hence the warning.  If the jars get packaged and the application works, then I guess you do not have a problem.

Comment: They don't get packaged. Maven doesn't pick them up.