# Getting error while using maven dependency for db2jcc.jar for db2 database connectivity?

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, db2

I am working on `DB2` database and i have created sample java program using maven to connect to `DB2` database.

Code are here:

```
String jdbcClassName = "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver";
String url = "jdbc:db2://192.168.1.63:50000/sample";
String user = "admin";
String password = "admin";
Connection connection = null;
try {
    //Load class into memory
    try {
        Class.forName(jdbcClassName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Establish connection
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
} catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch(SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I use `db2jcc.jar` through class path inside my code, then it was working but if I used `db2jcc.jar` through maven then it was not working.

Maven configuration is as follows:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.47</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cu</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.47</version>
        </dependency>
```

Error which i am getting are:-

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
at EzJava.main(EzJava.java:19)
```

Please help me on How to use `db2jcc.jar` through maven in my project.

Comment: get help from this git: https://github.com/mojohaus/sql-maven-plugin/issues/2 also DB2 drivers are a commercial product, and there are no official maven repositories for them. You must download the drivers from the official site: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866 and bind with project explicitly..or with maven .m2e repository...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382561/adding-db2-jars-to-java-webapp-using-maven

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding db2 jars to java webapp using maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382561/adding-db2-jars-to-java-webapp-using-maven)