# Unable to add IBM db2jcc4 jar file through Maven

Tags: java, maven, db2

I am trying to access DB2 tables in a java project. I am able to access the tables when I manually added the jar files - `db2jcc4.jar` and `db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar`. No issues in accessing the tables.

But when I try to add these jar files through Maven, they won't add to the project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
    <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
    <version>9.7.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Error Message - `Missing artifact id`.

Also, the latest `db2jcc4.jar` files (Version 11.1) are not present in Maven repository. Is there any other place I can access it from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382561/adding-db2-jars-to-java-webapp-using-maven

Answer (score 4):

You have to download the right driver from IBM. 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866

Then install it to your local maven repository
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html

Comment: I want it to be accessed by all team members. Installing it to my local maven repository would help only me. I want to have a common repository that can be accessed by all the team members.

Comment: Then you will need some sort of repository manager such as https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-sonatype

Comment: Thank you! For now, I have added it in one of our shared folders and referenced that in the Maven dependency.

Comment: can you please share how did you referenced it in the pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

As written in maven central repository the artifact is in another repo.
Add it to your pom and it will work.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Alfresco</id>
        <name>Alfresco</name>
        <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that , using share drive is the option to go.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>licences</artifactId>
            <version>0.7</version> <!-- Adjust this properly -->
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>R:\JDBC drivers\IBM DB2_db2_2.2.0.v20130525_0720\db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar</systemPath> 
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to maven central repository the artifact is in another repository. Include these two in your pom.xml and it should work:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
            <version>10.1</version>
        </dependency>

   <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>com.ibm.db2.jcc</id>
            <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```