# How to add external jar files to maven

Tags: java, maven-2, m2e

How do I add external jar files to maven web app project using Eclipse M2 Plugin?

Comment: What do you mean by "external jar file" ? Usually you add them as dependencies in Eclipse use Pom file view go to tab **Dependencies** and push button **Add** and type in coordinates.

Comment: I want to add a jar file that I added to my projects build path thats not in the maven repository.

Answer (score 1):

The most correct way is probably to install them to the repo.

However, for an alternate, see the top answer to:

[Can I add jars to maven 2 build classpath without installing them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364114/can-i-add-jars-to-maven-2-build-classpath-without-installing-them)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use mvn install:install-file.  See here for the instructions in the Maven guide:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html