# add external jar to our dependency

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

There is a jar file lets say "abc.jar" which maven dependency does not exist(ie created a jar by using java command of own classes). I want to  add this jar as maven dependency so that at build time  it will automatically copy that jar in lib folder as like other maven dependency. how i will do. please help .

Answer (score 1):

Add it as a dependency with a system scope. [See the docs here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies).

However, rather than adding it as a system dependency it might be better to mavenize the jar itself, then you can build and install it into your dependency management system.

Also, see this question: [Can I add jars to maven 2 build classpath without installing them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364114/can-i-add-jars-to-maven-2-build-classpath-without-installing-them)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `systemPath` attribute in the `dependency` tag in the POM file of your project.

In your pom.xml, use the following snippet corresponding to `abc.jar`:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <!-- Other dependencies -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>x</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>{path_to_abc.jar}</systemPath>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The `scope` parameter corresponding to this artifact must be set to `system`, for the artifact to be picked up from the specified `systemPath`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A normal maven dependency is always resolved by looking into a repository. So you must put your JAR file into a repository.

You could *install* your JAR into your local repository. Have a look at the [install plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/). The install-file goal is your friend.

If other developers also need this JAR (because they are working with the same project), they either need to install it locally too, or - better - you *deploy* the JAR to a remote repository. Have a look at the [deploy plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/). Here the deploy-file goal is your friend. For deploying artifacts, you need a repository manager like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) or [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/).

However, a dependency could also have the system scope (look at the other answers).