# Maven in-project repository doesn't work

Tags: maven, jar, repository, pom.xml, libraries

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<project ...>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>lib</id>
            <name>lib</name>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <url>file://${project.basedir}/src/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oracle.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
    <dependencies>
    ...
</project>
```

But there is an error shown on the <dependency> tag: **Missing artifact oracle.jdbc:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.4**

The directory structure is this way:

```
test-project/
  src/
    lib/
      oracle/
        jdbc/
          ojdbc6/
            11.2.0.4/
              ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar
```

Anything missing in the pom.xml file or wrong directory structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is start using a repository manager (Artifactory, Nexus, Archiva) and install the oracle jdbc driver there and than you can simply use it as a dependency.

If you really don't like to use a repository manager i can recommend the [non-maven-jar-maven-plugin.](https://github.com/stephenc/non-maven-jar-maven-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

After searching for hours, eventually found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21636497) works for me.

> Your settings.xml file declares a catch-all mirror. This takes effect over the local repository declaration in your pom file. Either remove the catch-all mirror, or try excluding the repository ID of your project repository from the mirroring:

Replace `<mirror>*</mirror>` with `<mirror>*,!lib</mirror>` in your `MAVEN/conf/settings.xml`

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution on Windows but it's quite funny:

Replace

```
file://${project.basedir}/src/lib
```

by

```
file://${project.basedir}\src\lib
```

Reference:
See the comment in: http://blog.dub.podval.org/2010/01/maven-in-project-repository.html