# ClassNotFoundException when running executable jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, noclassdeffounderror

I created a jar file for utility files and added it as a dependency for my main project. When I run `mvn install` to build my main project, the correct utility jar is used in my unit tests.

However, when I later run the main project jar using `java -jar supervisor.jar`, I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:` caused by `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.seeq.utilities.process.OperatingSystem`.

In my unit tests, `OperatingSystem` is used and the tests run fine, so I am assuming that the utility jar is not found when by java when using `java -jar`. Is that the issue and how could I fix it?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/seeq/utilities/process/OperatingSystem
    at com.seeq.supervisor.util.ProcessManager.buildCommand(ProcessManager.java:78)
    at com.seeq.supervisor.util.ProcessManager.<init>(ProcessManager.java:27)
    at com.seeq.supervisor.Supervisor.start(Supervisor.java:40)
    at com.seeq.supervisor.Main.main(Main.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.seeq.utilities.process.OperatingSystem
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 4 more
```

How I added the dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.seeq.utilities</groupId>
    <artifactId>seeq-utilities</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/../common/libraries/java/seeq-utilities/target/seeq-utilities-1.0.jar</ systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the not found class is inside a jar, you have to provide the classpath arguments; for example:

```
java -cp a.jar -jar supervisor.jar
```

Comment: I get the same error when I run ```java -cp ../common/libraries/java/seeq-utilities/target/seeq-utilities-1.0.jar:. -jar target/supervisor-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar```, but I'm not sure if the class path is the problem because shouldn't adding the dependency in Maven also add the jar to the class path?

Comment: I'm not sure why your solution didn't work for me, but it helped me find this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12746819/2386187) which worked.

Comment: @CoreyWu hi....sorry I must admit I was too fast. We have to separate things: if you want to execute JUnit tests by using maven, then you have to configure properly the pom.xml file; this means that you have o install in your local repository o you have to use the system scope for all the jars you can't download from maven repository; then if you want to execute the Java application with the java jar command, well you have to provide the -cp option in order that the java command knows where to find all the needed libraries. In maven this is don by the pom...Hope this helps, Angelo

Answer (score 0):

If you want to package your jar and its dependencies together into a single executable *uber* jar, consider using the maven shade plugin http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/.  An executable uber jar is convenient because you can run it immediately without extra "java -cp" steps.

An example pom plugin entry for an executable uber jar is show below (also see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html).

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.3</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <transformers>
               <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>org.example.MyMainClass/mainClass>
               </transformer>
            </transformers>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

This article also gives a nice overview of what the maven shade plugin can do: http://steveperkins.net/batteries-included-distribution-using-maven-shaded-jars/.

One annoying bug with the maven shade plugin is that it will give duplicate class warnings if you run `mvn package` more than once.  This issue is still unaddressed as of maven-shader-plugin 2.0: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSHADE-126).  To work around the issue, you can re-create your jar from scratch on each invocation, with the following maven-jar-plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.4</version>
   <configuration>
      <forceCreation>true</forceCreation>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Another issue that you may run into is that re-packaging signed jars invalidates their signatures.  If that causes errors for you, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6743609/1454388