# When trying to install jar in local repository using maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, repository, m2e

I do not have this SFTP jar in my Nexus Repo & I have add it's dependency into the POM file but now i want to install this JAR in my local repository so that i can use it in my project. But getting access is denied even though i opened command prompt with Administrator rights.

```
 C:\Windows\system32>mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.springframework.integration -DartifactId=spring-integration-sftp -Dversion=4.1.5 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=C:\Repo
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) @ standalone-pom
---
[INFO] Installing C:\Repo to C:\Users\t868396\.m2\repository\org\springframework
\integration\spring-integration-sftp\4.1.5\spring-integration-sftp-4.1.5.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.827 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-06-23T11:02:52+05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/64M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4
:install-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Error installing artifact
 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-sftp:jar': Failed to instal
l artifact org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-sftp:jar:4.1.5: C:
\Repo (Access is denied) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly likely the `-Dfile=your.jar` is not correct, check your argument (FYI it was omitted from your posting).

Here is an example:

```
mvn install:install-file -DlocalRepositoryPath=repo -DcreateChecksum=true 
 -Dfile=[your-jar] -Dpackaging=jar 
 -DgroupId=[...] -DartifactId=[...] -Dversion=[...]
```

See: [Can I add jars to maven 2 build classpath without installing them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364114/can-i-add-jars-to-maven-2-build-classpath-without-installing-them?lq=1)

And: https://maven.apache.org/general.html#importing-jars