# Maven , How to let dependency of local system jar be included into the output jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, build

I have a class ClassA in package packageA and ClassA import ClassB in packageB.(in fact ClassA import a lot of java file)

Then the directory is ：

```
root
    pom.xml
    src 
         packageA
                  classA
                  pom.xml
         packageB
                  classB
```

**My goal is to generate a jar include classA and classB by only telling maven that I input classA.**

the pom.xml in the packageA directory is like

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>D:\path\to\my\local.jar</systemPath>
        <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
        <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!--other dependency in maven repo-->
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> 
                    <phase>package</phase> 
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <sourceDirectory>.</sourceDirectory> <!--if I don't add this line ,the output jar will not include anything of my own project-->
</build>
```

You know, if I don't add `<sourceDirectory>.</sourceDirectory>` it will not build any thing.But if I add`<sourceDirectory>.</sourceDirectory>`,the output jar only contains the `<sourceDirectory>`'s path's classes and the dependencies of maven repo , without my jar of local system path

(In fact the local jar of my own is to support the `<sourceDirectory>`'s path's classes' build .Also in fact the local jar contains the classB)

**Why my own jar's related classes have not been added in the output jar?**

Comment: I would recommend using a war File to include Java Classes from different Projects.

Comment: You'll need to scroll through the answers as there is no accepted. This appears to be the most comprehensive answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7623805/360211