# Class file from a external jar not found during maven build?

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-2

I have created a runnable jar which i included in my project(Maven Project).
But when i tried doing mvn clean package. My build gets failed It gives me an error in one of my class imports stating that the package does not exist(which is present in jar).

What i tried:

1. Tried adding the jat in Web App Libraries.
2. Adding the  jar as external jar.
3. Adding it in lib folder.

Error Message:

```
 Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project interplan: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] ..\..\..\MyVehicles.java:[11,40] error: package com.vehicles.parts.manager does not exist
```

Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the error message and pom file

Comment: Jens : Its not included in pom file. I have created an external jar by self and want to add. Please understand before voting to close. Its a maven based project. I want this jar to be added externally.

Comment: This post will help .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-in-maven-project

Comment: Then Google bevor asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364114/can-i-add-jars-to-maven-2-build-classpath-without-installing-them

Comment: Please check how to include 3rd party jars in a maven project. You need to use the scope in pom.xml.

Comment: Could you tell us the name of your external jar?

Answer (score 15):

You need to install your `external jar` in local repository in following way:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=c:\kaptcha-{version}.jar -DgroupId=com.google.code -DartifactId=kaptcha -Dversion={version} -Dpackaging=jar
```

and add the following dependency in pom:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code</groupId>
      <artifactId>kaptcha</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
 </dependency>
```

Please replace the values of your `external jar` for `c:\kaptcha-{version}.jar`.

Build again and tell me the result.

You may also look at http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/