# Add classpath pointing to jars in Maven

Tags: maven, classpath

I have lot of external jar files that needs to be pointed in the project. Since these jar files will be available on end users system by default, I am maintaining config parameter file which will hold that directory location.

Is there any way to include this classpath in maven?

Comment: You don't need to; you can simply have your classpath updated with the required location while invoking your project.

Comment: the OP wants to include an external jars directory in classpath as dependencies when they are not coming from a repository like this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/including-all-the-jars-in-a-directory-within-the-java-classpath?rq=1

but within maven and unfortunately, there is no easy way other than adding them to your repo or as artifacts or maniuplating classpath as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364114/can-i-add-jars-to-maven-2-build-classpath-without-installing-them