# How to pass additional classpath dependencies to testCompile phase in maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

I want to compile test files using some external jar dependencies which will not be present in pom.xml's dependency tag. Is there any way through configuration. Something like this-

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.5</source>
    <target>1.5</target>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>test-compile</id>
      <configuration>
        <classPathElements>
            <classPathElement>somejar.jar</classPathElement>
        </classPathElements>
      </configuration>
    </execution>

  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Just a little question. Do you need to compile your tests classes with external JARs, or do you need to execute tests with external JARs?

Comment: Actually both , but for execution I am using maven-surefire-plugin.. for which there is option to pass external jars using <additionalClasspathElement> tag

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? (Besides the fact that you can't).

Comment: @tunaki I have a different folder structure for my project and I am overriding most of the lifecycle phases of maven. Also , these jar dependencies will be project specific which will not be there in .m2 repo

Comment: @tunaki right now I am trying to resolve this issue by overriding test-compile phase

Comment: That raises even more question. Why are you overriding lifecycle phases, and what is the connection with this? You can define your own lifecycle, no need to override anything. And why are you trying to use JARs which are not in the local repository?

Comment: basically I have created my own junitTestSuit which will be using one of our product and it has multiple plugin dependencies.. which we can not install in .m2 repo.. so the need

Comment: That doesn't answer the previous questions. Why can't you install that in a local repo, or use a repository manager? And why are you overriding Maven default lifecycle? The point is, you cannot do what you're trying to do. You want to add JARs during compilation, but not declare that JAR as a dependency, which is going against the very notion of using Maven to begin with. It sounds like you may need to create your own plugins, with your own lifecycle, instead of trying to override things you cannot, by design.

Comment: Its our products requirement .. and yes.. I am creating my own lifecycle to resolve this requirement now..

Comment: Approach like : [maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path/2230464#2230464) and [can-i-add-jars-to-maven-2-build-classpath-without-installing-them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364114/can-i-add-jars-to-maven-2-build-classpath-without-installing-them#364188) can help you maybe. I think the second one is interesting in your if your problem is to not use the .m2 repo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it includes libraries from your project

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mylib</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.mylib</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/mylib.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```