# Maven does not find local dependency

Tags: java, maven, repository, maven-3, pom.xml

**TL;DR**

Maven does not find `<importedGroupid>:<importedArtifactid>:jar:1.0` in repository `file://<homeDirectory>/.m2/repository/`. The package actually is in `<homeDirectory>/.m2/repository/<importedGroupid>/<importedArtifactid>/1.0/`

I do not presume to understand Maven, but the two potential reasons I could imagine are:

- it gets confused with `:` and `/` (i.e. UNIX style path seperator vs. whatever `:` means in Maven), or
- if `:` and `/` are actually interpreted as the same, the path it searches for includes another subdirectory level `jar` that is not present in the real directory structure.

**Detailed Explanation**

I was trying to import a package locally in Maven (as the package is not deployed online). Various answers (e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7623805/1735215), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4955695)) on stackoverflow recommend running `mvn install` on the jar containing the package like so (assuming the jar is in `/usr/share/java`, is version 1.0, etc. etc.):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/usr/share/java/<importedArtifactid>-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=<importedGroupid> -DartifactId=<importedArtifactid> -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=JAR -DgeneratePom=true
```

and defining this in the current package's `pom.xml` by adding:

```
<repository>
  <id>repository</id>
  <url>file://${user.home}/.m2/repository/</url>
</repository>
```

The `mvn install` command deploys the package into `<homeDirectory>/.m2/repository/`. So far, this works fine:

```
<prompt> $ mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/usr/share/java/<importedArtifactid>-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=<importedGroupid> -DartifactId=<importedArtifactid> -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=JAR -DgeneratePom=true
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building <currentDirectoryProject> 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) @ <currentDirectoryProjectArtifactid> ---
[INFO] Installing /usr/share/java/economicsl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to <homeDirectory>/.m2/repository/<importedGroupid>/<importedArtifactid>/1.0/<importedArtifactid>-1.0.JAR
[INFO] Installing /tmp/mvninstall256012398997457078.pom to <homeDirectory>/.m2/repository/<importedGroupid>/<importedArtifactid>/1.0/<importedArtifactid>-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.489 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-11T19:11:12+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/292M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
<prompt> $
```

The package also appears in `<homeDirectory>/.m2/repository/`

```
<prompt> $ ls `<homeDirectory>/.m2/repository/<importedGroupid>/<importedArtifactid>/1.0/`
<importedArtifactid>-1.0.JAR              <importedArtifactid>-1.0.jar.lastUpdated  <importedArtifactid>-1.0.pom              _remote.repositories
<prompt> $
```

However, building the project that attempts to import the package fails:

```
<prompt> $ mvn package -U
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building <currentDirectoryProject> 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: file://<homeDirectory>/.m2/repository/<importedGroupid>/<importedArtifactid>/1.0/<importedArtifactid>-1.0.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/<importedGroupid>/<importedArtifactid>/1.0/<importedArtifactid>-1.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.730 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-12T17:59:43+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/292M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project <currentDirectoryProjectArtifactid>: Could not resolve dependencies for project <currentDirectoryProjectGroupid>:<currentDirectoryProjectArtifactid>:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact <importedGroupid>:<importedArtifactid>:jar:1.0 in repository (file://<homeDirectory>/.m2/repository/) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
<prompt> $
```

If an absolute path to the jar in `/usr/share/java` is defined in the `pom.xml`, the project builds successfully with a warning about not using absolute paths, but execution fails as it does not find the package again this time.

Maven version is Apache Maven 3.3.9.

**Placeholders**

- `<currentDirectoryProject>` The project that is supposed to import the other package. All terminal commands are executed from the root directory of this project (this is where its `pom.xml` resides).
- `<currentDirectoryProjectArtifactid>` ArtifactID of the project that is supposed to import the other package.
- `<currentDirectoryProjectGroupid>` GroupID of the project that is supposed to import the other package.
- `<importedArtifactid>` ArtifactID of the project that is to be imported
- `<importedGroupid>` GroupID of the project that is to be imported
- `<homeDirectory>` the user's home directory, i.e. `/home/<userName>`
- `<prompt>` terminal prompt

Comment: Just noticed that you have a file extension "JAR" in upper case and maven is looking "jar" in lower case. If your file system is case sensitive, then that's important.

Comment: @gogstad Yes, you are absolutely right. (Consequently, `mvn install` must be called with `-Dpackaging=jar`, not with `-Dpackaging=JAR` to fix this.) If you could re-post this as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a file extension "JAR" in upper case and maven is looking "jar" in lower case. If your file system is case sensitive, then that's important.

Comment: God bless you for this answer, I have been driving myself insane trying to figure out why this build setup I inherited worked fine on our OSX machines and failed in the Linux CI environment I've been trying to set up