# IntelliJ doesn't see Dependency trough Manifest.MF

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, weblogic

I have a Maven Project where i need to use OracleWeblogic 12.1.1.
This is a migration from an ANT Project.

I have added the weblogic.jar as a dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
        <artifactId>weblogic</artifactId>
        <version>12.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${env.WL_MIDDELWARE}/wlserver_12.1/server/lib/weblogic.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

In my code there is a reference to

```
weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException;
```

In Eclipse (old version of the Project) i added the weblogic.jar manually to the Classpath and the TimedOutException is loaded correctly trough a chain of jar files via the MANIFEST.MF in the weblogic.jar

In Intellij (new Version with MAVEN) i added the dependency but the class can not be resolved.
(Apparantly

Duiring `mvn package` or `install` everything works fine (no compilation errors) because as i expect the jar file is loaded from disk with the correct relativ location of the other jar files.

But during development inside IntelliJ it is always stated as missing. Also building the project inside IntelliJ does not work because i get a `cannot find symbol` error.

Can someone explain me how to deal with this situation in IntelliJ?

Also I have tested removing the MAVEN dependency of the weblogic.jar and try to add it manuelly into the classpath (inside IntelliJ) but this also does not work.. (same behavoir as in MAVEN)

Is intellij not capable to see all referenced jar files? Am I missing a setting?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA doesn't support it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6988.

Comment: So there is no workaround or anything i can use to at least build inside IntelliJ?

Comment: Add all the required jars individually.

Comment: there are more than 100+ Librariers referenzed by weblogic...

Comment: One can [generate the XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37221449/104891) for `pom.xml` for all the jars in a directory.