# How to integrate external packages in java?

Tags: java, import, bluetooth, package

I'm trying to develop an app that uses Bluetooth technology, so I need javax.bluetooth & javax.obex & javax.microedition packages. I've downloaded it but I don't know how to properly place it and where so the Java can see it while compilation. How do I integrate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what tool you're using to create your jar. For example: [Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364114/can-i-add-jars-to-maven-2-build-classpath-without-installing-them), [Eclipse](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/07/eclipse-how-to-add-external-jar-into-classpath.html) or [IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project). Usually you can find an answer that is relevant to your build method by simply googling it.

However, if you want to permenantly add them to your JDK, you'll have to paste them in your JDK's integrated jre into the following folder: \jre\lib\ext

For me that would be:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext

[image: My Folder]

As you can see, I added RXTX (a serial comm library) to mine and I can now use it in my code.

Comment: I'm not using any IDE, the thing is these packages are not in the standard edition so I need to integrate it separately. I know that I can just place it in my project's package but it would be a bad design and I would have to do it again when I need it in the next project.

Comment: Ah, so you want to add them to your JDK's library? Wait, I'll add that to my response...

Comment: Done with the modification!