# Add external libraries in a maven web application in NetBeans

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, web-applications, netbeans, libraries

I want to add an external .jar containing an API to a project created with the template maven-web application in NetBeans.
It seems that in a project created with such template the Libraries folder doesn't exist (you don't find it both if you go to Project Properties and if you look under the project file structure).

I managed to add the library by copying the jar into the project and editing the pom.xml file like this:

> ```
>    <dependency>
>     <groupId>Bbg</groupId>
>     <artifactId>BbgAPI</artifactId>
>     <scope>system</scope>
>     <version>1.0</version>
>     <!-- <systemPath>C:\blp\BPipe\APIv3\JavaAPI\v3.7.1.1\bin\blpapi3.jar</systemPath> -->
>     <systemPath>${basedir}\lib\blpapi3.jar</systemPath>
>  </dependency>
> ```

The code compiles file but I get an error at Runtime:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/bloomberglp/blpapi/SessionOptions

My guess is that the JVM cannot find the class definition in the classpath.
Typically, when adding external libraries to a standard java project in NetBeans (via the Libraries section in Project Properties) the classpath is automatically updated, but in this case (by manually editing the pom.xml) it seems that this has not happened.

Do you know how I can patch the classpath to make the classes visible at runtime?
In general, do you know why this project template doesn't allow to add external libraries in the standard way?

Thanks

Comment: Best bet it is to install it into your local repo first. See [here](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But this supposes that I have maven installed and runnable from commmand line, while I use maven via the "maven" plugin of netbeans. I can't run "mvn" from Windows terminal nor from NetBeans internal terminal. So how can I install the jar in the maven local repository? Do I need to install maven from outside NetBeans? Is this compatible with using NetBeans maven plugin. I guess that an external installation it's gonna mess up maven integrationin NetBeans.

Comment: Good question. Never had to do that. See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/321137/2587435) helps

Comment: I followed the instructions there, manually installing the artifact, but this hasn't solved the problem. I can successfully build the project but still I can't see the library at Runtime. Do you know if there's a way to explicitly set the classpath in such a project?

Comment: What do you mean _"can't see the library at Runtime"_? Do you mean when you run the main jar, you're getting a NoClassDefFound? Usually Netbeans will set the classpath for you in the MANIFEST. And the classpath will point to the `lib` (where the dependencies are) in the `build/dist`. Check it out. If you want the classes from that other jar packaged into the main jar, you will need an uber jar plugin  like [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) or [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)

Comment: Let me check to confirm (about the manifest). Oh and also make sure that the jar you are trying to add as a dependency, doesn't depend on another jar. It happens. It is _other_ jar, something of yours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after checking, after following the instructions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/339874/2587435), to add the dependency to the project, you still need a couple things. If you just build the project like this, one thing you'll notice, if you look at the project in the "Files" window, is that your jar is not there.

To copy your the jars to a location, you should use the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html). Something like

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Doing this, you should see the the dependency in the `lib` in the `target` dir

Then to set up class path, use the [maven-jar-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>test.app.main.TestClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Doing this, is you look at the `MANIFEST`, you should see the `lib/yourDepenendency.jar` in added to the `Class-Path` attribute. You should be able to run the jar

"Files" view of project. `test-app-main` is the main Maven project. I main a simple java project `test-app` in which I create a jar from.

[image]

If you want to include the classes from the other jar in the main distribution jar, you will need a plugin like like [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) or [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)

---

### **UPDATE**: For the most part, ignore everything above. I just noticed you're create a webapp

Just doing the below and building your project should make the jar *"available"* for the webapp

1. From your project, right click on the "Dependencies" -> "Add Dependency"
2. Make up a arbitrary name for the groupId, artifactId -> version, click ok
3. Right click on the jar from the "Dependencies", select "Manually Install Artifact". Locate the artifact and add it.

Doing this, once you build it, the jar should be available in the `WEB-INF/libs` where it should be for webapps

Just keep in mind though, when doing it this way, you need to make sure the jar you are trying to use isn't dependent on any other jars

Comment: Great! This (the UPDATE part) has worked. Even if the jar hasn't appeared in WEB-INF/libs (I don't even have the lib folder inside WEB-INF).
As to my understanding, adding the dependency using the "wizard" to add the dependency (right-click etc..) has added some lines in the pom.xml (as I did manually in my first attempt) plus something else (probably linking the classpath someway). Just to end up this issue: do you know exactly what is this "something else"?

Comment: _"Even if the jar hasn't appeared in WEB-INF/libs"_ - Go to [Window] -> [Files]. Look for your project and open the [target] dir. You will see the .war file. Open it and you will see WEB-INF.lib. That's where the dependency gets built to. That's where the server will look for it. _"has added some lines in the pom.xml "_. Nope. Just standard coordinate mapping. When you "Manually Install Artifact", it just added the jar to your local repo so you can use it as you normally would with any dependency you get from the repo.