# install lib before dependency check with Netbeans Maven?

Tags: maven-3, netbeans-8

There is a similar solution: [how-do-i-install-modules-into-the-maven-repository-using-netbeans-embedded-maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321137/how-do-i-install-modules-into-the-maven-repository-using-netbeans-embedded-maven), but that's manually install.

Following the post: [Adding a custom jar as a maven dependency](http://blog.valdaris.com/post/custom-jar/), I have the pox.xml:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>my-local-repo</id>
        <url>file://${basedir}/lib</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-file</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <groupId>my.store</groupId>
                <artifactId>store</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
                <file>${basedir}/lib/MyStore.jar</file>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.store</groupId>
    <artifactId>store</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

but when I load this project, maven will warn

```
Building
------------------------------------------------------------------------
The POM for my.story:story:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
```

It seems like although the plugin execute phase is initialize, it didn't execute before dependency check.
thanks for the help.

P.S. there is a decency-plugin, does this matter?

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <compilerArguments>
            <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
        </compilerArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                <silent>true</silent>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>javax</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                        <version>7.0</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm so sorry, there is already an answer: [how-to-run-maven-plugin-before-dependency-check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120227/how-to-run-maven-plugin-before-dependency-check), I should try

```xml
<phase>clean</phase>
```

before.